# Element is not clickable at point (693, 14). Other element would receive the click: With Chrome Driver only

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi all i am using selenium backed webdriver i am automating some third party site so i don't have any access to the code of that site problem is that my selenium test case works well firefox but when i use chromedriver it gives an exception **Element is not clickable at point (693, 14). Other element would receive the click** i read on some blog that using the lines of code makes the problem go the lines are given below

```
WebElement elementToClick = driver.findElement(By.id("create_item_button"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0," + elementToClick.getLocation().y + ")");
elementToClick.click();
```

But this does not help can any one suggest me any work around for that my code is as given below

```
            selenium.click("//img[@alt='Upload']");
    selenium.click("link=basic uploader");
            WebElement fileUpload = driver.findElement(By.id("file-box"));

    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,"+fileUpload.getLocation().y+")");

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    fileUpload.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Shoaib\\Desktop\\kkk.java");
```

Comment: Generally, it means that element you're trying to click is: a) moved to different position (e.g. animation); b) overlapped by some other element. If you can give an example of HTML and code you use, it'd be much easier to figure it out.

Comment: I am using third party site which is https://www.box.com/ i am trying to click its create item button and i am using the same code to click that button in firefox it works fine but in chrome it gives that exception

Comment: Do we have any other work arounds to deal with the issue other than the one i am using

Comment: Just try the same code (in Ruby) and it worked ok for me using ChromeDriver 23.0.1240.0, Chrome 23.0.1271.101 and Selenium 2.27.1. Not sure why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: here it is my code i am  trying to upload file  selenium.click("//img[@alt='Upload']");
  selenium.click("link=basic uploader");
  

  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,"+fileUpload.getLocation().y+")");
        
  
  fileUpload.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Shoaib\\Desktop\\kkk.java");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging "Element is not clickable at point" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error)

Answer (score 0):

You can move the mouse to the location of the element and then click, using actions:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);   
builder.moveToElement([VisibleElementThatIsNearby], [XOffset], [YOffset])
    .click()
    .build()
    .perform();
```

where `VisibleElementThatIsNearby` is an element that you can identify with no problems, and `XOffset` is the amount left/right you need to move from there to click on the element, and `YOffset` is the amount up/down you need to move to click on the element.