# Chromedriver missing the element to click

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Chromedriver seems to be missing the element it is supposed to click:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("html body div#colorbox div#cboxWrapper div div#cboxContent div#cboxClose")).click();
```

executing this line throws "WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point(xxxxx) Other element would receive a click." I tried xpath, id, cssSelector locators - every throws the same exception

Comment: Sounds like an element is infront of the one you want to click. Wrap it in a `WebDriverWait` to see if it eventually becomes clickable. http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Not every div is clickable.Maybe there's a span or button at child node.That's clickable.Wish it can help you.

```
<div>
<span id='test001'>it's clickable</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a common issue, it can sometimes be solved by making sure the element is on screen, for instance by using `new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).click().perform();` This is detailed here: [Debugging "Element is not clickable at point" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error), though it isn't foolproof either.