# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, jquery-selectors, html.dropdownlistfor

I use selenium webdrive to select an item in a drop down list.

[image]

[image]

I want to click on `"game club"` element

I have tried few elements, but I get an error that non of them is clickable.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (790, 227). Other element would receive the click: <div id="select2-drop-mask" class="select2-drop-mask" style=""></div>
(Session info: chrome=41.0.2272.3)
```

However, using the browser I click on the item for sure.

How can I click on this item?

Comment: May be this link will help you...


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error/19419366#19419366

Answer (score 0):

If this is a static list I would use the `SelectElement(IWebElement element)` method.

C# Example:

```
  var dropDown = _webDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("select2-result-sub"));
  var dropDownSelector = new SelectElement(dropDown);
  dropDownSelector.SelectByIndex(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
public void click( By element ) {
    WebElement button = driver.findElement( element );
    try {
        button.click();
    } catch ( WebDriverException e ) {
        List<WebElement> availables = button.findElements( By.tagName( "div" ) );
        availables.addAll( button.findElements( By.tagName( "span" ) ) );
        tryClick( availables );
    }
}

public void tryClick( List<WebElement> availables ) {
    for ( WebElement candidate : availables ) {
        try {
            candidate.click();
            return;
        } catch ( WebDriverException e ) {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

after that use(for example):

```
click(By.id("elementId"));
```

regards!