# Selenium C# : Not able to click on an element within #shadow-root (closed) which appears when user mouse over

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, shadow-dom

[image]

I have attached  the screenshot for my code and marked the element that i need to click in red.
This element appears after we mouse over on another object - and mouse over is successful and i can see this element get displayed, but failed to click on it

My code is

```
var LinksSurce = sourceThumb.FindElement(By.ID("linkSource"));
     LinksSurce.Click();
```

Error i am getting is Element not intractable

NOTE: i have already read and tried the solutions suggested on these posts but none of them working
[Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (x, y). Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-elem)

[Debugging "Element is not clickable at point" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error)

[Selenium - Element is not clickable at point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508143/selenium-element-is-not-clickable-at-point)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the screenshot you have shared the element is clearly within a **`#shadow-root (closed)`**.

We have been discussing about [Shadow DOM traversal support](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5869) through [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) for quite some time now and the key take aways are:

- @43081j mentioned, for closed shadow roots it should just be accepted that you can't access it (throw an exception). So, we don't need to care about closed roots as we shouldn't be able to access them anyway.
- @AutomatedTester in his [spec proposal](https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/pull/1320) suggested the ability to move between a Shadow DOM context and the document context.

So currently you won't be able to interact with the elements within the `#shadow-root (closed)`.

---

### Conclusion

If the `#shadow-root` had been **open** we could have easily interacted with the desired element. You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to interact with the elements within #shadow-root (open) while Clearing Browsing Data of Chrome Browser using cssSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-interact-with-the-elements-within-shadow-root-open-while-clearing-brow)
- [How to automate shadow DOM elements using selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium/55763793#55763793)

---

### Alternative

[Shadow root DOM automation using selenium](https://github.com/sukgu/shadow-automation-selenium#shadow-root-dom-automation-using-selenium)

---

### References

A couple of pull requests:

- [support shadow DOM when reading element text](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/4230)
- [add shadow dom v1 support to DOM atoms](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/5762)