# Element not clickable using Selenium webdriver with Chrome (same code:works fine using firefox)

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Using selenium-2.44.tar.gz and chrome for automating test cases:Very strange my code works fine using Firefox 33 but fails using Google Chrome:

> "WebDriverException: Message: u'unknown error: Element is not
>   clickable at point(57, 161). Other element would receive the click: ...\n
>   (Session info: chrome=42.0.2311.135 )\n  (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)'"
>   self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//[@id='searchMessagstoryBtn']").click()

any idea? shouldnt it work better with chrome one wonders since webdriver is Google code nowdays or am I wrong!!!

Comment: See this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error

Answer (score 1):

Unlike firefox, to use chromedriver you have to download chromedriver from http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ and had to give path in your code.
**You can use the below code, to use chrome driver in java or in python**
 Java:

```
public void testGoogleSearch() {
  // Optional, if not specified, WebDriver will search your path for chromedriver.
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");

  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.google.com/xhtml");
  Thread.sleep(5000);  // Let the user actually see something!
  WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
  searchBox.sendKeys("ChromeDriver");
  searchBox.submit();
  Thread.sleep(5000);  // Let the user actually see something!
  driver.quit();
}
```

Python:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.get('http://www.google.com/xhtml');
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in ChromeDriver.
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2766

Try this workaround solution from form #27. I hope it would help you:

> I ran into this same issue as well with Chrome...clicking the element
>   works fine in firefox but not in Chrome...the fix is pretty easy
>   though, all you have to do is scroll the element into view before
>   clicking it, and you won't run into this problem in Chrome. Here's the
>   code i use:
>
> IWebElement elementToClick = ;
>
> // Scroll the browser to the element's Y position (driver as
>   IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript(string.Format("window.scrollTo(0,
>   {0});", elementToClick.Location.Y));
>
> // Click the element elementToClick.Click();
>
> Hope this helps anyone else who runs into this issue

Comment: Hi thanks, is there any chance you can give me the code in python and any needed import thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//[@id='searchMessagstoryBtn']")
private WebElement Search_btn;

public WebElement getSearchBtnClick() {
    return Search_btn;
}

public void Click_Search_Btn() {
    //click the search button
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
    getSearchBtnClick().click();
}
```