# Element is not clickable at point (194, -212) need to scroll

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am running grunt-protractor-runner.

`protractor: 2.0.0
jasmine: 1.3
Linux Ubuntu 14.4`

---

I am having issues while clicking the next page button and get error below.

> UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (194,
>   -212) (Session info: chrome=42.0.2311.90) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457
>   (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Linux
>   3.13.0-49-generic x86_64) with stack trace`
>
> UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (194,
>   -212) (Session info: chrome=42.0.2311.90) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457
>   (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Linux
>   3.13.0-49-generic x86_64) at new bot.Error (/home/hasan/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:113:18)
>   at Object.bot.response.checkResponse
>   (/home/hasan/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/response.js:106:9)
>   at
>   /home/hasan/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:377:20
>   at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_
>   (/home/hasan/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1877:20)
>   at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify
>   (/home/hasan/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:2464:25)
>   at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_
>   (/home/hasan/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:563:12)
>   at Array.forEach (native) at Object.goog.array.forEach
>   (/home/hasan/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/array/array.js:203:43)
>   at [object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_
>   (/home/hasan/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:552:16)
>   at [object Object].goog.async.run.processWorkQueue [as _onTimeout]
>   (/home/hasan/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/async/run.js:125:21)
>   Error at [object Object].ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_
>   (/home/hasan/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.js:403:21)
>   at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as click]
>   (/home/hasan/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.js:76:19)
>   at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as click]
>   (/home/hasan/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.js:733:11)
>   at [object Object].

---

With reference to a thread at stackoverflow [Debugging "Element is not clickable at point" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error) I worked around and here is my code

```
it("It should click next page botton" + pageIndex, function() {
    pageIndex++;
    //var nextPageSelector = element(by.id("pageNavigator_" + pageIndex));
    var nextPageSelector = element(by.xpath('//li[@class="next"]/a'));
    browser.debugger();
    //expect(browser.isElementPresent(nextPageSelector)).toBeTruthy();
    console.log("Page title: " + pageTitles.length + "Page index" + pageIndex);

    if (pageIndex <= pageTitles.length) {
        console.log("About to click next button");
        //console.log("Co-ordinates: "+ nextPageSelector2.getCoordinates());
        nextPageSelector.getLocation().then(function(buttonLocation) {
            console.log("X coordinate: " + buttonLocation.x + " Y Coordinate: " + buttonLocation.y);
            var sc = '"scroll(' + buttonLocation.x + ', ' + buttonLocation.y + ')"';
            console.log("Statement: " + sc);
            browser.actions().mouseMove(buttonLocation.x , buttonLocation.y);//.click().perform();
            //browser.executeScript(sc); //
            browser.wait(2000);
            nextPageSelector.click().then(function() {
                console.log("Successfully clicked");
                browser.waitForAngular();
            }, function() {
                console.log("Unable to click");
            });
        });

    }
});
```

I didn't get hold to scroll to the location of "next page" button.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: have you tried maximizing the browser window: `browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();`?

Comment: Thanks but it did not help.

Comment: This trick works for me                                 
var filterWidget = browser.findElement(by.id(widgetsId));
                                var scrollView = function() {
                                    arguments[0].scrollIntoView();
                                };
                                browser.executeScript(scrollView, filterWidget);

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Just post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

This trick works for me:

```
var filterWidget = browser.findElement(by.id(widgetsId)); 
var scrollIntoView= function() { arguments[0].scrollIntoView(); }; 
browser.executeScript(scrollIntoView, filterWidget);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the window size in your config file.

In your protractor.conf.js:

```
onPrepare: function() {
  browser.manage().window().setSize(1600, 1000);
}
```