# Element is not clickable at point (339, 85). Other element would receive the click

Tags: hadoop

Below is the current HTML DOM.

```
&lt;div class="addr notChooseOpera right" click="switchPanel" un="contact"&gt;&lt;a class="addrButton " href="javascript:;" title="通讯录"&gt;&lt;span class="bag"&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
```

I'm using python+selenium+WebDriver to execute this method

```
self.browser.find_element_by_class_name("addrButton").click()
```

But get this error：

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
>   Element is not clickable at point (339, 85). Other element would
>   receive the click: <div class="addr notChooseOpera right"
>   click="switchPanel" un="contact">...</div>   (Session info:
>   chrome=36.0.1985.143)

Comment: This might help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error

Comment: please use the correct tags... Selenium e.g. instead of hadoop

Comment: @kukeltje thanks, I would pay more attention :)