# Chromedriver Element is not clickable at point (xxx, yyy). Other element would receive the click:

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting the following dreaded error when using Chromedriver with Selenium:

```
"org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (xxx, yyy). Other element would receive the click: ..."
```

I know this has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11908249/1119381)

However my situation is a bit different in the sense if I put a delay of about 5s and then click it works fine. I don't have to do anything special, just wait.

I know I can force a click by using JS or Actions, but I want a more elegant way of handling this i.e. only click button when button becomes clickable. The problem is I don't know how to check and see if the button is clickable or not.

I've tried the following but neither work:

```
1) ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable
2) ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf
```

Any ideas?

Comment: i guess I could write a method which keeps trying to click until it succeeds in clicking i.e. try/catch with delays? Would this be considered an elegant solution? I hate having to put thread.sleeps everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two options you could try:

**JavaScript**

Check the `Document.readyState` property that describes the loading state of the document:

```
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) input;
return jsExecutor.executeScript("return document.readyState;").equals("complete");
```

You can just wait for it to become "complete". Might not be work in many cases but worth a try.

**Loop**

That's probably the simplest solution. Not sure about its elegance but should do the job without wasting more time than needed (This is just a very basic example, this code should not be used as-is):

```
while (true) {
    try {
        element.click();
    } catch (WebDriverException e) {
        // ignore
        Thread.sleep(millis);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. The loop option is last resort as I don't think it's elegant. I will test the JS version and let you know.

Comment: @ratsstack well, keep in mind that many "pretty" implementations are basically performing the same loops just internally :) For example, have a look at the `until` method in Selenium `FluentWait` class. This is what it does basically.

Comment: Sorry, I am not clear on what the "input" would be in this case?

Comment: @ratsstack This is your `WebDriver` instance

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks will try.

Comment: @ratsstack, While loop should have some timeout otherwise code will be in infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I handled this using custom waitAndClick() method which uses recursion as following:

int waitCounter = 0;

```
// Wait for an element to become clickable

public static void WaitAndClick(WebElement elementToBeClicked) throws InterruptedException, IOException {


    try
    {


        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);



        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(elementToBeClicked));
                wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elementToBeClicked));

        elementToBeClicked.click();

    }

    catch(Exception  e)

    {
        MethodLibrary.Logger_Info("Element not clicked yet. waiting some more for " + elementToBeClicked);

        if(waitCounter <3){

            waitCounter++;

            WaitAndClick(elementToBeClicked);
        }

        waitCounter = 0;


    }



}
```