# Why doesn't my 'Wait Method' click on the intended button?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Why doesn't my wait method click on the intended button?

```
    public void waitAndClickElement(WebElement element) throws InterruptedException {
    this.wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    Boolean elementPresent = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)).isEnabled();
    try {
        if(elementPresent==true){
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element)).click();
            //clickElementUsingJS(element);
        }else {
            System.out.println("The specified element cannot be found: " + element);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw(e);
    }
}
```

If I use Thread.sleep infront of the method it seems to click on the button:

```
    @Test(priority=4) 
public void clickOnFirstSuperCarOption() throws Exception 
{
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    basePage.waitAndClickElement(supercarsPage.link_FirstSupercarOption);
}
```

[image]

Locator:

```
public @FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='prd_listing']/div/li[1]/a") WebElement link_FirstSupercarOption;
```

Comment: Which exception are you getting?

Comment: @acikojevic this is an example exception which im getting: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: .//*[@id='prd_pg_rgt']/div[2]/form/div/input (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Comment: The element `By.xpath: .//*[@id='prd_pg_rgt']/div[2]/form/div/input` cannot be found. Try to find out what that element is. I don't see you mention it in the question

Comment: @Linh Nguyen the element is a strong link, it seems to work when running some test cases but not on others, think its wise just to add a Thread.sleep inside the method; doing this makes the method work

Comment: Could you show the html part where it contains `id=prd_pg_rgt`, and the code where you look for the element `By.xpath: .//*[@id='prd_pg_rgt']/div[2]/form/div/input `?

Comment: Please refer to my answer [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490572/chromedriver-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-xxx-yyy-other-element-would-r/41740240#41740240); it might help you.

Comment: Please refer to my answer [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490572/chromedriver-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-xxx-yyy-other-element-would-r/41740240#41740240); it might help you.