# Clicking on an element in Selenium to bring up File Upload window doesn't work

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver

In facebook navigate to Home and try to click on Add Photos/Videos to bring up the file upload window but it always gives an exception "Element is not clickable at point ..."

I tried the methods given in the first answer of [Debugging "Element is not clickable at point" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)
 but nothing works.

Edit:

Code:

1.

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Add Photos/Video']"));
element.click();
```

2

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Add Photos/Video']"));
element.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

3

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
```

4.

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Please provide more info on what you have tried... code samples, etc.

Comment: @JeffC code samples added

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor ex = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver;
ex.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", elementToClick);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be JavascriptExecutor and not IJavaScriptExecutor ? If so then I have tried it and it doesn't work

Comment: In general you shouldn't use JSE because it's not how the user would interact with the page.

Comment: @JeffC But I've seen JsE work when all other alternatives have failed. So it can be useful.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said, "in general..." but it was suggested in this case when the non-JSE case worked fine. I think many fall back to JSE because it makes the case work when they haven't taken the time to do it the right way... the way a user would. In the end, many use methods that don't simulate user actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Actions](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) `moveToElement`

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver); // initialize Actions instance 
actions.moveToElement(elementToClick).performe(); // scroll the screen to make the button visible
elementToClick.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and it worked... the File | Open dialog opens.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div._3jk")).click();
```

Comment: It works. But I am a bit concerned because this locator identifies both Add Photo/Video and Create Photo Album in Firepath. So how unique and safe would this locator be?

Comment: I don't know... I haven't tested it but you could and find out for yourself.