# Using Selenium for clicking on button Python

Tags: python, selenium

When I click this button in Selenium, I get an error telling me:

```
Element is not clickable at point(245, 19)
```

The button element

```
input type="submit" id="login_submit" name="login_submit" class="red-button" value="Login"
```

I've tried a couple of ways,

```
driver.find_element_by_id("login_submit");
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="submit" and @name="login_submit"]');
```

I'm using firefox as the driver

One thing that is weird about this is that it will actually work once, and then stopped working after that for some reason (usually after a reboot it works), I don't know want the reason for this.

Don't know if it matters if the image of the button changes if you highlight it with your pointer.

Thank you for any help you can give

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check out this answer from another thread?
"Debugging “Element is not clickable at point” error"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19763087/4428117

The issue is that **the button is not visible to click** 
or
**page is getting refreshed before it is clicking the element.**

Comment: Thanks, it seem to have the info, I just maximize the page (button was off the page when I loaded it)