# Selenium-Debugging: Element is not clickable at point (X,Y)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-firefoxdriver

I try to scrape this [site](http://www.auchandrive.fr/) by Selenium.

I want to click in "Next Page" buttom, for this I do:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('pagination-r').click()
```

it works for many pages but not for all, I got this error

```
WebDriverException: Message: Element is not clickable at point (918, 13). Other element would receive the click: <div class="linkAuchan"></div>
```

always for [this page](https://www.auchandrive.fr/drive/Nice-Cote-dAzur-869/Produits-Frais-R3686962/Traiteur-3686315/;jsessionid=D1CEED79373B4043E52D56E1D0E96A37.27BC109326910D9522BB1D9773F60A)

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error)

and I tried this

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
el = driver.find_element_by_class_name('pagination-r')
action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(el, 918, 13)
action.click()
action.perform()
```

but I got the same error

Comment: When I go to that page there is no element with the class name, `pagination-r` or `linkAuchan`. I guess the page has changed?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Another element is covering the element you are trying to click. You could use `execute_script()` to click on this.

```py
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('pagination-r')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: @RemcoW  what is the meaning of `arguments[0]` here?

Comment: @chandresh The `execute_script()` method has 2 parameters. The first is the script, the second is a vararg in which you can place any parameters used in the script. In this case we only need the element as parameter, but since it is a vararg our element is the first in the collection. For example you could also do `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click(); arguments[1].click();" element1, element2)` This would click both elements passed

Comment: Bear in mind, if you are writing tests that intend to use the website like a real user you are potentially doing something that a real user cannot do because the element they want to click on is covered.  Don't do this to just make your tests pass!

Comment: @CKM driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element) - `arguments[0]` is `element`. You can do driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();doSmthElse(arguments[1])", element, doSmthElseParam) and in this case `arguments[1]` would be `doSmthElseParam`

Answer (score 29):

Because element is not visible on the browser, first you need to scroll down to the element
this can be performed by executing javascript.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('pagination-r')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: `arguments[0].scrollIntoView();` is crucially missing from the currently accepted answer. This works perfectly.

Comment: arguments[0].scrollIntoView() is crucial INDEED!!! This made my day, and helped me so much in 2022. Thank you,

Comment: driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
thank you so much about this

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar issue where using ActionChains was not solving my error:
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (5
74, 892)

I found a nice solution if you dont want to use execute_script:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys #need to send keystrokes

inputElement = self.driver.find_element_by_name('checkout')

inputElement.send_keys("\n") #send enter for links, buttons
```

or

```
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.SPACE) #for checkbox etc
```

Comment: can we click too after sending keys??

Comment: @AbhishekGupta - The idea is that we can use keystrokes to simulate the action like link click or button click etc. - Instead of using the mouse. What is your scenario where you need both?

Comment: Everything else was not working in my case (a checkbox). Sending Keys.SPACE worked like as magic.

Answer (score 3):

I have written logic to handle these type of exception .

```
   def find_element_click(self, by, expression, search_window=None, timeout=32, ignore_exception=None,
                       poll_frequency=4):
    """It find the element and click then  handle all type of exception during click

    :param poll_frequency:
    :param by:
    :param expression:
    :param timeout:
    :param ignore_exception:list It is a list of exception which is need to ignore.
    :return:
    """
    if ignore_exception is None:
        ignore_exception = []

    ignore_exception.append(NoSuchElementException)
    if search_window is None:
        search_window = self.driver

    end_time = time.time() + timeout
    while True:
        try:
            web_element = search_window.find_element(by=by, value=expression)
            web_element.click()
            return True
        except tuple(ignore_exception) as e:
            self.logger.debug(str(e))
            if time.time() > end_time:
                self.logger.exception(e)
                time.sleep(poll_frequency)
                break
        except Exception as e:
            raise
    return False
```

Comment: It is more efficient than other available option . Us ElementClickInterceptedException in ignore_exception list .

Comment: very good solution! I have added ElementClickInterceptedException and ElementNotInteractableException in the ignore_exception, set timeout to 3 seconds, and works like a charm.

Comment: I still get the same error after using the above.

Answer (score 2):

If you are receiving an `element not clickable` error, even after using wait on the element, try one of these workarounds:

- Use `Action` to move to the location of `element` and then run `perform` on `action`

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By("element_path"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform();`
```

- Check for an overlay or spinner on the `element` and `wait` for its invisibility

```
By spinnerimg = By.id("spinner ID");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(spinnerimg ));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: you can use markdown to format the code in your answer, which enhances readability. For example: `WebElement element = driver.findElement(By("element_path")); ` Just wrap the code with the backtick character: `

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit wait instead of implicit.

```
new WebDriverWait(TestingSession.Browser.WebDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.ClassName("pagination-r'"))));
```

Comment: Can you rewrite it in python please

Comment: Sorry dude. I never worked on python, though you can get help on explicit waits in python.

Comment: ExpectedConditions.ElementExists will not be helpful in this case. Element has been found but is not clickable

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue with Chrome driver, changing the `PageLoadStrategy` of chromeOptions from 'Eager' to `Normal` fixed my problem.

```
chromeOptions.PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Normal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a heads up, we were having this problem because we were doing `.click()` on a `Submit` element. You can do `.click()` on `Button` ***OR*** `.submit()` on `Submit`, one of the two, but you shouldn't mix up these two methods.

`.click()`
`.submit()`