# Element not interactable selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to check out on the nike webstore but I have tried everything and searched and can't find an answer to it.

https://www.nike.com/nl/nl/checkout/tunnel

I have:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@id="qa-guest-checkout-mobile"]').click()

<button id="qa-guest-checkout-mobile" aria-label="Guest Checkout" 
class="ncss-btn-accent u-rounded u-full-width ncss-brand u-uppercase pt3-sm pt2-lg pr5-sm pb3-sm pb2-lg pl5-sm fs14-sm d-lg-h">
<span class="d-sm-ib va-sm-m mr1-sm">Afrekenen als bezoeker</span></button>
```

I have tried to use find by id, css and more, but it isn't working. What am I doing wrong here? When I print the elements I only get 1 element and I dont get an error then.

```
  File "C:\Users\X\OneDrive\Desktop\SN\NA.py", line 23, in <module>
    test = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@id="qa-guest-checkout-mobile"]').click()
  File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After a good amount of searching I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879010/selenium-debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y) with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37880313/10924296) and was able to make this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.nike.com/nl/nl/checkout/tunnel')
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div/button[@id='qa-guest-checkout-mobile']")))
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Which successfully clicks on the button. For some reason you have to force click the button using javascript...

Comment: it's because the element can't be interacted by a real user, selenium is made to emulate a real user navigating the website, but javascript will ignore these assertions that selenium does(visible, interactable, clickable, etc...) and directly call the click event for the element.

Comment: @Valga Yes, I understand the mechanics of selenium, but good idea to make a note of them! I tried the wait condition for it to be visible, which timed out (20 second wait time). I also couldn't seem to find anything that would cover it within the HTML...It seemed to me the only solution was to force click it once it was located "under" some other element, but if you know of another solution I would love to see you post it and drop a ping for me to look at it!

Comment: @Reedinationer, thank you mate. This is working for me, but can you maybe explain me how this is working?

Comment: @Number70 I would recommend you look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34796379/10924296) that explains the difference between clicking with `.click()` like you were trying to do, and clicking through javascript like this answer uses. Hope that helps!

Comment: @Reedinationer, thanks I will check it.

Comment: can please someone help me in doing the same in JS instead of Python? I don't know what to import and how to use it!