# selenium.common.exceptions.elementnotinteractableexception message element not interactable

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Here is the link:
"https://btlaesthetics.com/en/find-a-physician"

I have searched a zip code '6292' in location search box by using selenium (as shown in code below). And it searches and shows results. Now it clicks on "Show details" of each clinic(section) 1 by 1, and it does so, but the main issue I'm facing is that, it scrapes data(telephone, email, website) of 1st section, each time it clicks on each section's detail, rather than scraping each section's own data.
Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:\python\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get("https://btlaesthetics.com/en/find-a-physician")
driver.maximize_window()

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='inp-text filter-address-input pac-target-input']")
element.send_keys("6292")
element.send_keys(u'\ue007')
element.send_keys(u'\ue007')
element.send_keys(u'\ue007')
element.send_keys(u'\ue007')
element.send_keys(u'\ue007')
element.send_keys(u'\ue007')
element.send_keys(u'\ue007')
element.send_keys(u'\ue007')
element.send_keys(u'\ue007')
element.send_keys(u'\ue007')
element.send_keys(u'\ue007')
element.send_keys(u'\ue007')
time.sleep(3)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

item_provider_near = soup.find_all('div', class_='item-provider')
for each in range(len(item_provider_near)):
    each = "(//a[@class='toggle-more'])[" + str(each+1) + "]"
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(each).click()
    time.sleep(3)
    phone = soup.find('span',class_='provider-phone').text
    email = soup.find('span',class_='provider-email').text
    website = soup.find('span',class_='provider-website').text
    if phone:
        print(phone)
    else:
        pass

    if email:
        print(email)
    else:
        pass

    if website:
        print(website)
    else:
        pass
driver.quit()
```

At the end, after scraping, it shows error: selenium.common.exceptions.elementnotinteractableexception message element not interactable

Comment: Please use this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56194094/how-to-fix-this-issue-element-not-interactable-selenium-python

Comment: hey @sonulohani, now it hasn't show any error, but still shows the same results i.e. 1 section data

Comment: Can't you use try except block. If the elementnotinteractableexception exception is raised then pass it in except block.

Comment: No, it is not giving the error now, but showing wrong results, i.e 1st section data of each section

Comment: Oh I see... It is still showing data in html without even clicking on "show detail". Thanks