# Selenium hidden / wrapped elements \ lists

Tags: python, list, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to understand why the following code does not work. I am intending to send a key to a search input that is on a different web tab and then press a button.  After reading similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56194094/how-to-fix-this-issue-element-not-interactable-selenium-python) in the forum I think the element might either be hidden or wrapped. How to find this? Also sometimes the elements are in a list and have to be accessed by indexing. The examples I have studied are not like that.  Any help will be appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import *

 
webdriver_path = "C:/Users/escob/Documents/Projects/WebScrapingExample/chromedriver.exe"

magpie_url = 'https://www.musicmagpie.co.uk/start-selling/'
search_item = "9781912047734"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browser = webdriver.Chrome (webdriver_path, options = options)
browser.get(magpie_url)

sell_tab = browser.find_element_by_id('pills-media-tab')
sell_tab.click()

##I have tried the following code with no luck
#search_bar = browser.find_elements_by_name('searchString')
#search_bar = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('form-input')
search_bar = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='searchString']")

#I am getting elements in a list, the examples I have seen do not need indexing
search_bar[0].send_keys(search_item)


button = browser.find_element_by_class_name(submit-media-search) #will this work?
button[0].click()  #again in a list?
```

Thank you so much for your help from a beginner Seleniumista.

Comment: My answer is able to solve the use case in your question.  Please let me know when you have tested my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish with search, so I can only provide guidance on searching for your string *9781912047734*.  The code below will enter the search string and click the add button.

I noted that the page has an *"accept cookies button"*, so I added the code to bypass this.

Please let me know if this code helps you.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

# Hide the "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software" banner
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
url = 'https://www.musicmagpie.co.uk/start-selling'
response = driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

hidden_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "cookieBar")))
if hidden_element.is_displayed():
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Accept all cookies').click()
else:
   pass


tab = driver.find_element_by_id('pills-media-tab')
tab.click()

# this implicitly_wait is waiting for the page to fully load
driver.implicitly_wait(60)

# this xpath can likely be refined 
enter_barcode = driver.find_element_by_xpath("*//div[3]/div/form/div/div[1]/div[1]/input")
enter_barcode.send_keys("9781912047734")

# waiting for the keys to be sent
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

add_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.form:nth-child(19) > "
                                                  "div:nth-child(1) > form:nth-child(1) > "
                                                  "div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > "
                                                  "input:nth-child(1)")
add_button.click()

# do something else

# call close when finished
driver.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It was useful to learn about hidden_element.   What I'm trying to achieve is to send keys to the search bar that is in the second tab "Sell CDs, DVDs, Games & Books"). I have managed to click on the tab by  running this code 
sell_tab = driver.find_element_by_id('pills-media-tab')
sell_tab.click()


But I am unable to find the search bar and send the key. I have tried this: 
search_bar = driver.find_elements_by_name('searchString')
search_bar[0].send_keys("9781912047734")

button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('submit-media-search')
button.click(

Comment: So you want to input the search string on the "Sell CDs, DVDs, Games & Books"?  Let me update my answer to do that.

Comment: @GustavoAEscobar-Palafox I added the code to input a barcode and add it to the basket.  I didn't add the error handling code for any items that might not be accepted.  You will need to do this.  Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have just tried the code and it is perfect. I learnt so much, thanks. I have added error handling so all is good. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm glad that I could help you solve your problem.  Please accept my answer.