# Press a button from popup window with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
# Add experimental options to remove "Google Chrome is controlled by automated software" notification
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\iwanh\Desktop\Drivers\chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")

# We use driver.find_element with the help of the By import instead of find_element_by_name or id


accept_all = driver.find_element(By.ID, value="text")
time.sleep(7)
accept_all.submit()
```

So i have this code, and what i am trying to do is press the accept all button on the screenshot but I think the code doesnt recognize it with the id because it is some what of a popup window?
And here is the inspect element

[Inspect Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMDvD.png)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/693dN.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the element and go to Copy > Copy (full) xpath.

Then use:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, 'xpath_value_here')
```

Edited to reflect the difference between 'copy xpath' and 'copy full xpath'; indeed, copy full xpath is the correct answer, as per the below comment.

Comment: I did that but now it says element not interactable

Comment: @GiannisTsakas Perhaps this method? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56194094/how-to-fix-this-issue-element-not-interactable-selenium-python

Comment: Found it, instead of the XPATH i copied the thing that says COPY FULL XPATH
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65556052/19136755