# How to extract location link using selenium webdriver python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I was using the below code snippet to extract the "Locations" link using selenium webdrive in python, but not able to extract the link, was only able to extract the text ("Locations"). Can anyone help me in this?

Link to extract from: https://www.thomasnet.com/company/siemens-corporation-10035100/profile?cov=NA&which=comp&what=Siemens+Corporation&cid=10035100&searchpos=1

[image]

Code Snippet used:

```
lnk_content = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='__next']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/button/span")
lnk = lnk_content.get_attribute("href")
print(lnk)
```

Comment: There is no `href` attribute in the targeted `span` element. Obviously nothing will be extracted.

Comment: But there is a link in the "Locations" button, is there a way to extract that?

Comment: Where is the link? Do you see it in the HTML DOM?

Comment: Clicking that links works because there is a `click` event listener attached to the `<button>` element that contains that `Location` link. There is no link to extract contained in the HTML itself. This is probably designed explicitly to prevent web scraping. Using Selenium, you could perhaps click the link and then read the URL of the page that gets loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with larks comment. See the below code to click on Location element and extract the URL which gets loaded.

Code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.thomasnet.com/company/siemens-corporation-10035100/profile?cov=NA&which=comp&what=Siemens+Corporation&cid=10035100&searchpos=1")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//span[text()='Locations'])[2]"))).click()
time.sleep(5)
location_url = driver.current_url
print(location_url)
```

Console:

```
https://www.thomasnet.com/company/siemens-corporation-10035100/branches?pg=1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on that link makes new content visible in the existing document. You can click on the link with code like this:

```py
lnk = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[span[text() = "Locations"]]')

# See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56194349/147356
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", lnk)
```

Then you can retrieve the location table:

```py
locations = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[h2[text() = 'Locations']]/following-sibling::div/table")
```

And iterate over the rows:

```py
for row in locations.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr'):
  ...
```