# How do you fix the “ElementNotInteractableException” exception?

Tags: python, selenium

Unable to interact with quantity selector on the product page but its never working on the checkout page.

Used the code below which shows me if the element is being detected and its always showing false.

```
  print("Element is visible? " + str(quantity_checkout.is_displayed()))
```

This is the error that I am receiving:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not 
 interactable (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.150)
```

Below is my entire code

```
print(web_link)

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get(web_link)

# Facebook Share button working
# submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="Share on Facebook"]')

# print("Element is visible? " + str(quantity.is_displayed()))

# Change Quantity
quantity = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="quantity"]')
quantity.clear()
time.sleep(1)
quantity.send_keys('5')
time.sleep(1)

# Add to cart
add_to_cart = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@data-label="Add to Cart"]')
add_to_cart.click()
time.sleep(5)

quantity_checkout = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="updates_10389617349"]')
print("Element is visible? " + str(quantity_checkout.is_displayed()))
quantity_checkout.clear()
time.sleep(1)
quantity_checkout.send_keys('10')
time.sleep(3)

checkout = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="action_button add_to_cart bold_clone"]')
checkout.click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@id="bold-modal__btn-close"]').click()
time.sleep(4)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Maybe the element takes time to load. Have you tried explicit wait? For further help, you can give the link

Comment: Yea I tried setting the timer even for a whole minute, but the code I posted is timing that I am looking for. Plus its not this website I have tried multiple its seems to be a thing with shopify checkout pages

Comment: and the weblibk address

Comment: Strongly advise you to go through the similar questions on SO.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44119081/how-do-you-fix-the-element-not-interactable-exception

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56119289/element-not-interactable-selenium

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56194094/how-to-fix-this-issue-element-not-interactable-selenium-python


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868009/how-to-resolve-elementnotinteractableexception-element-is-not-visible-in-seleni