# Element <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0);"> is not clickable at point (x,y ) because another element <span> obscures it

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find a button which has Quick Move-In as the content.

```
<li>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="active">
                            94 Quick Move-In Homes
<span class="len-tip-item bottom">
<i class="far fa-info-circle"></i> 
<span class="len-tip-box" style="display: none;">
An inventory home that is either under construction or completed.
</span></span></a></li>
```

My code looks like this.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

python_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(., 'Move-In')]")
python_button.click() #click link
```

I am not sure why am I getting this error:
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element  is not clickable at point (1257,736) because another element  obscures it

Comment: Is that the entire error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium-Debugging: Element is not clickable at point (X,Y)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879010/selenium-debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error?rq=1

Comment: @AMC the first link helped. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a wait and wait for the element to be clickable before attempting to click it.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By    
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.implicitly_wait(30)
python_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(., 'Move-In')]")))
python_button.click() #click link
```

You can use waits for wait for other expected conditions, as well.  You can find more info here:  https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: But now it gives me this error:" TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given" at   "//a[contains(., 'Move-In')]"

Comment: I was missing a ) at the end of a line.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Actually, I did fix that error earlier, but it still gives me this error

Comment: I wasn't at my laptop to try it, but have since corrected the syntax.  You shouldn't get the type error any longer.