# Selenium find_element throwing exception even though the element exists

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**My code:**

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,features="html.parser")
applications_domains = []

for card in soup.find_all("div", {"class":"ant-row"}):
    for url in card.find_all("a"):
    applications_domains.append(url.get("href"))

for aplications_domain in aplication_domains:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//a[@href='" + 
applications_domain + "']")))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='" + applications_domain + "']").click()
    except:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,features="html.parser")
        print(soup.find_all("a",{"href":applications_domain}))
        print(f"test error {applications_domain}")
        print("-----------------------")
```

I have an issue with `find_element_by_xpath` not finding the element even though it exists. I double checked using `soup` if indeed the element exists and it does as per output.

**Output:**

```
<a href="applications_domain"><b></b></a>
test error applications_domain
```

I have a loop that goes through each application domain (contains data from each `href`) however, it finds and clicks on the `a href` element most of the time but does not for some and I have no idea why.

Here is the site html. There are many `div id="application_name_list"` and each contain different `a href` that I need to click through

```
<div class="ant-row" style="margin-left: -6px; margin-right: -6px;">
<div id="application_name_list" class="ant-col-8 dyff-home-app-search-result-item" style="padding-left: 6px; padding-right: 6px;">
    <a href="/dyfflaunch/domain/gco/app/di_data_customer_experience_conversation_processor/features">di_data_customer_experience_conversation_processor<b></b></a>
</div>
<div id="application_name_list" class="ant-col-8 dyff-home-app-search-result-item" style="padding-left: 6px; padding-right: 6px;">
    <a href="/dyfflaunch/domain/gco/app/di_kafka_configservice_agentqueuegroup_dim_v1-prod/features">di_kafka_configservice_agentqueuegroup_dim_v1-prod<b></b></a>
</div>
<div id="application_name_list" class="ant-col-8 dyff-home-app-search-result-item" style="padding-left: 6px; padding-right: 6px;">
    <a href="/dyfflaunch/domain/gco/app/di_kafka_configservice_phoneinventory_dim_v1-prod/features">di_kafka_configservice_phoneinventory_dim_v1-prod<b></b></a>
</div>
</div>
enter code here
```

Comment: Is your code the exact one you ran or just the mock up? I see the for loop is not correct. You are appending urls in "applications_domains" list and you are looping through "aplication_domains".

Comment: @Roitko : Can you share your url or relevant HTML?

Comment: @AzharSyed Sorry, I made a spelling mistake. Fixed now.

Comment: @Kunduk added html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by overlapping and solved as per [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879010/selenium-debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y/37880313)
Error message returned was `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point`but due to my poor knowledge of error handling the error was not shown as expected. Thank you all for help!

Comment: you would have mentioned that error in your original post.It would have resolved two hours before.

Comment: @KunduK I was not aware of the error as I did not output it. It was my beginner mistake and I apologize for wasting everyone's time!

Comment: I am not harsh.I hope you understood what i mean.Its lesson learned always provide more information like if you are getting any error which helps OP to provide resolution towards problem.All the best.Happy Learning.

Answer (score 0):

This is one, pretty generic way of doing it:

```
a_tags=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='application_name_list']//a")

for a_tag in a_tags:
    a_tag.click()
```

If you have examples where this doesn't work, please add one to the question.

Comment: added 3 examples that it is not working for. Thank you for pointing it out

Comment: If you compare the structure for one that works and one that doesn't, is there anything different whatsoever? One thing that comes to mind for example, is whether you have an `iframe` somewhere higher above `<div id="application_name_list">`.

Comment: I checked whole html and there is no `iframe`. I tried comparing the htmls before submitting this but they have the same structure. Here is one working as an example. `<div id="application_name_list" class="ant-col-8 dyff-home-app-search-result-item" style="padding-left: 6px; padding-right: 6px;">
 <a href="/dyfflaunch/domain/gco/app/di_kafka_configservice_agentqueuegroup_dim_v1-prod/features">di_kafka_configservice_agentqueuegroup_dim_v1-prod<b/>
 </a>
</div>`

Comment: I see the working example has a white space as text() value for the `a` node, but I'd be extremely surprised if that's what makes the difference. I see the `div`s are the result of a search, correct? Are some of these results outside the visible screen i.e. do you need to scroll to reach them? And if so, are these (the ones outside the visible screen) the results which fail? If that is the case, use `ActionChains` to bring the element in focus: `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(a_tag).click().perform()`.

Comment: these examples are on the top of the site. Nevertheless I will try to use this code instead and see what happens. Will let you know if it worked or not.

Comment: I am still receiving the same errors. I will try to use text of the `a href` tag instead of `href` value and see if it helps.

Comment: I found out what was causing the issue. The only thing that was different from the  working links was the length of text. After further testing I found out that links are overlapping on the screen. See https://prnt.sc/rvhumn for more information. Do you know by any chance how this could be fixed?

Comment: Found the solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879010/selenium-debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y/37880313)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use WebDriverWait() and wait for `visibility_of_all_elements_located`() and then use following css selector to click.

```
driver.get("url here")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".ant-row")))
for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".ant-row>#application_name_list>a[href]"):
    link.click()
```

---

If you want to use beautiful soup and selenium to do that then try this one.

```
driver.get("url here")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".ant-row")))

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,features="html.parser")
applications_domains = []

for url in soup.select(".ant-row>#application_name_list>a[href]"):
    applications_domains.append(url['href'])

for applications_domain in applications_domains:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//a[@href='" + applications_domain + "']")))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='" + applications_domain + "']").click()
    except:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,features="html.parser")
        print(soup.find_all("a",{"href":applications_domain}))
        print("test error {applications_domain}")
        print("-----------------------")
```

Comment: what bothers me the most that the `a href` is there as it is in `applications_domains` list as well as it is find-able using `soup`. I will try to do another `WebDriverWait`.

Comment: @Roitko : The sample html which you have posted is working fine to me.If it possible to share url then I would be in a better position to know why this isn't working for you.Thanks.

Comment: unfortunately I am not able to share the HTML as it is working only on extranet. However, thank you for looking into this!