# Closing Random Video Pop Up Ad which covers my "Load More" Button in Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am scraping roughly 1000 urls using selenium, and I am very close to having it work. Each url has a "load more" button that I continuously click until a Stale Element exception is thrown, which is passed. The scrape works great until a random video ad covers the button. I thought using XPATH to locate the button would solve the issue, but it does not. I know using java to execute the script will solve the issue, but I am not sure how to use on a looping basis. Below is what I have at the moment.

```
    if clicks >= 1:
        webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()
        sleep(1)
        try:
            while EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/ html / body / div[2] / div / div / div[4] / div[4] / div / div / button')):
                button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/ html / body / div[2] / div / div / div[4] / div[4] / div / div / button")
                button[0].click()
                sleep(2)
                if not button.is_enabled():
                    print('ad is covering button, hopefully this works')
                    wait2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
                    wait2.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH("/ html / body / div[2] / div / div / div[4] / div[4] / div / div / button").click()))
                    
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            pass

    else:
        print('under 10 reviews')
        pass
```

my hope was the if not line would save the day... but I am not sure if I am setting it correctly. I have also found this link may be helpful: [Selenium-Debugging: Element is not clickable at point (X,Y)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879010/selenium-debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y) , but I do not know how to continuously click using the execute script feature.
This link may also be helpful as well: [WebDriver click() vs JavaScript click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562061/webdriver-click-vs-javascript-click)
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply rework it into this. Pretty sure you need a timeout except as well. In case it doesn't find it.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
while True:
    try:
        elem=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[.='load more']")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        break
    except TimeOutException:
        break
```

Comment: Arundeep! Great to hear from you again. You have once again saved me. Also, if you'd like to edit your answer. I threw in a except StaleElementReferenceException:break, except TimeOutException:break, and it runs fine. Thanks again!