# Why Cant I Click an Element in Selenium using python and Chrome Webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I use Selenium-python to scrape [this page](http://www.ooshop.com/courses-en-ligne/ContentNavigation.aspx?TO_NOEUD_IDMO=N000000013081&FROM_NOEUD_IDMO=N000000013056&TO_NOEUD_IDFO=81018&NOEUD_NIVEAU=2&UNIVERS_INDEX=2) and click on Pagination numbers.

i try this one:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
time.sleep(5)
driver.get(
    'http://www.ooshop.com/courses-en-ligne/ContentNavigation.aspx?TO_NOEUD_IDMO=N000000013081&FROM_NOEUD_IDMO=N000000013056&TO_NOEUD_IDFO=81018&NOEUD_NIVEAU=2&UNIVERS_INDEX=2')
nbdespages = 23

for i in xrange(2,nbdespages):
    time.sleep(10)
    number = str(i)
    if(i<10):
        cssSelec = 'ctl00_cphC_pn3T1_ctl01_rptPaginationB_ctl0%s_lbPage' %number
    else:
        cssSelec = 'ctl00_cphC_pn3T1_ctl01_rptPaginationB_ctl%s_lbPage' %number
    try:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, cssSelec)))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", element)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(cssSelec).click()
    finally:
        driver.save_screenshot('/Users/Parik/Desktop/test.jpg')
        print "TRY Again, you will find"
```

but i got this exception:

```
TimeoutException: Message:
```

i use **WebDriverWait** because sometimes i got this error if i don't use it and i read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error) and use it for my problem:

```
 Element is not clickable at point
```

the value of css selector is correct

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:51099/session/ddf78c5a19e720909cbe6a0f5408788e/element {"using": "css selector", "sessionId": "ddf78c5a19e720909cbe6a0f5408788e", "value": "ctl00_cphC_pn3T1_ctl01_rptPaginationB_ctl02_lbPage"}
```

**UPADTE1**

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

With Screen shot i see that i can't see the numbers, i changed my code to this:

```
    try:
        element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('img#ctl00_cphC_pn3T1_ctl01_rp_ctl15_ctl00_iVisu.image')
        driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", element)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(cssSelec).click()
    finally:
        driver.save_screenshot('/Users/Parik/Desktop/test.jpg')
        print "TRY Again, you will find"
```

and now i see the Pagination 
[image]

but i have always this exception:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"ctl00_cphC_pn3T1_ctl01_rptPaginationB_ctl02_lbPage"}
  (Session info: chrome=51.0.2704.103)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.5 x86_64)
```

Comment: i think first u need to scroll down to make the pagination number visible. do it and let me know what happens ... if ok i will convert it to answer.

Comment: You need to execute `javascript` to perform click like this `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element)`....hope it will work..

Comment: @noor i upadet my code, but i have the same problem

Comment: @SaurabhGaur i added scrolling, but it doesn't help

Comment: @parik I'm telling about click not about scrolling...

Comment: click like this `element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, cssSelec)))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element)`

Comment: @parik take a screen shot when you get an exception. And see whats blocking your click. browser.save_screenshot('screenie.png')

Comment: And then include that screen shot in your question.

Comment: @HassanMehmood thanks for your suggestion, i added it

Comment: @SaurabhGaur i added your suggestion in my code and i took a screen shot

Comment: Ok so now you can clearly see that Element you want to click is not visible.

Comment: By the way here is a quick work around. You can visit the next page by changing the URL.

Comment: @HassanMehmood for the URL i think that you're wrong, with wich url i can see the second page? i changed my code and know i see the page numbers ( i added it to my question)

Comment: @parik what happened when did you click using js??...

Comment: @SaurabhGaur i get the exception.

Comment: @parik try using xpath

Comment: @parik..ok forget everything... just use like this `try:driver.execute_script("document.getElementById(arguments[0]).click();", cssSelec)`..

Comment: @SaurabhGaur thanks  a lot man, it works, can you post it like answer please, maybe it can help someone else too.

Comment: @parik yeah sure posted it like a answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try `.execute_script` to perform click as below :-

```
try:driver.execute_script("document.getElementById(arguments[0]).click();", cssSelec)
```

You can also try as below :-

```
try:
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, cssSelec))
)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", element)
```

**Note :-** you are preparing locator for `id` but using as `By.CSS_SELECTOR` to finding the element, for that reason you are getting exception as `NoSuchElementException`, so change it to `By.ID`.

You can also use `element.click()` but if you are getting `Exception` as like `Element is not clickable at point`, I suggest you can use here `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", element)` to perform `click`.

Hope it will help you..:)

Answer (score 0):

`cssSelec = 'ctl00_cphC_pn3T1_ctl01_rptPaginationH_ctl0%s_lbPage' %number` and 
`cssSelec = 'ctl00_cphC_pn3T1_ctl01_rptPaginationH_ctl%s_lbPage' %number` refer to the id's for the elements you're trying to click and are not applicable CSS selectors by themselves - you *can* use them in a CSS selector using the *#* symbol like so:

`a#ctl00_cphC_pn3T1_ctl01_rptPaginationH_ctl02_lbPage`

Another method you could use to locate and click the elements is to use WebDriver's link text locator as the elements are anchor (`<a>` tag) elements.

I would highly recommend you avoid using Javascript to click the elements as this a hack at best and opens up potential for Javascript errors in your tests.

Comment: i added a# but i got this error : WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (151, 8). Other element would receive the click: <div id="ctl00_IdCookies_HeadBandCookie" class="BandeauCookie">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=51.0.2704.103)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.5 x86_64)