# Error in selenium when running firefox

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting below error when I try to click on one element in `Firefox` browser.

> Element is not clickable at point (320.2166748046875, 55). Other element would receive the click: `<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>`

Selenium code

```
WebElement p = driver_new.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/form/fieldset[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/a[1]/div/div/div[2]"));
p.click();
```

Please help to resolve it.

Comment: please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error. Also there are many more question on same issue

Comment: Also try this as well https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/element-is-not-clickable-at-point-selenium-webdriver-exception

Comment: Could you share your HTML as well..

Comment: @huges what version is your firefox?

Comment: had this issue before. try setting the browserwindow to full hd resolution and see if it can click the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have tried all but didn't get success, you should try using `javascriptExecutor` to perform `click` as below :-

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;

WebElement bp = driver_new.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/form/fieldset[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/a[1]/div/div/div[2]"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver_new).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", bp);
```

Comment: @huges import class first using `import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor`....:)

Comment: @huges it's there,  `J` in upper case, see updated answer..:)

Comment: Thanks a lot bro:)