# Proper xpath for identifying the checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write an selenium script using `xpath` to `click` on the checkbox but am unable to perform the operation rather i am getting an error

> Element is not clickable at point (210.5, 616). Other element would receive the click: Command duration or timeout: 75 milliseconds

html:

```
<div style="float:left;">
<label class="enhanced-checkbox" for="lender_user_privacy">
<i class="icon"/>
</label>
<input id="lender_user_privacy" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" type="checkbox" value="1" required="required" name="lender_user[privacy]"/>
</div>
```

xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id = 'lender_user_privacy']")).click();
```

Note: Could you suggest me the right `xpath` for clicking on the checkbox as i am getting the above error when i write the above `xpath`

Comment: have you tried waiting for some time and then performing the click? is the element hidden?

Comment: no its a checkbox...i did try using wait but the input id is for the text next to the checkbox ,as when i identify the checkbox using firepath ,this line of html is highlighted(<label class="enhanced-checkbox" for="lender_user_privacy">).Is there anyway wherein i navigate back to the parent which is the checkbox ?

Comment: The problem is not on the xpath. You have a problem with another component overlaping your checkbox. Check this for possible reasons http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the comment, to navigate back to the parent you can use xpath's parent expression `/..`.
If `.//input[@id='lender_user_privacy']` is identifying you the label, that' a child of the checkbox, then you can access the checkbox using

```
.//input[@id='lender_user_privacy']/..
```

as your xpath. However, the wait is most likely necessary considering the error that you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

xpath seems to be correct. Use explicit wait. Following code is in c#:

```
try { 
    WebDriverWait wt;
    wt = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    wt.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(driver.FindElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='lender_user_privacy']")))).Click();
} catch(WebDriverException) {
    // do some actions on exception if you want
}
```

Comment: i did try using wait but the input id is for the text next to the checkbox ,as when i identify the checkbox using firepath ,this line of html is highlighted(<label class="enhanced-chec‌​kbox" for="lender_user_pri‌​vacy">).Is there anyway wherein i navigate back to the parent which is the checkbox ?i did try using wait but it is with the same error...