# Appium not clicking on an element

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium, ui-automation

I'm trying to automate one of my `hybrid` app using `Appium`. I'm getting an issue while clicking on the Login button. The error message I'm getting is:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (116, 329). Other element would receive the click: `<button class="button  button-medium button-custom-login " ng-click="login()">...</button>`

And I just want to click on the same element i.e. the one mentioned here with attribute `ng-click="login()`.

I've changed the context already to `WebView` and tried with changing the attribute to Native as well but nothing seems to be working.

The code which I've used to identify this element is below:

```
List<WebElement> labels = driver.findElementsByTagName("button");
```

I iterated through all the elements and found that I need to click on number 20 element.

Any help on this would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Try using `Actions` class as `Actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform()` and let me know..:)

Comment: Hi Saurabh, Yes this particular code worked for me. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You should try using `Actions` class as below :-

```
WebElement element = driver.findEle....
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have found that you need to click on number 20 element in the list, you could go this way:

```
int pos = 20;
List labels = driver.findElementsByTagName("button");
labels.get(pos-1).click();
```

Comment: Tried this one already and this is also not working. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: does `driver.findElementsByTagName("button");` returns anything?

Comment: Yes it does. It return around 25 elements. I retrieved the text of all the elements and found that number 20 is the Login button which I want to click and when I click on it using the .click method I get an error. It shows that "Other element would receive the click" and I need to click on this other element only which it is not doing.

Comment: check this link then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error

Comment: Hey Shahid, The link which you have provided has worked. Below code worked for me:
Actions actions = new Actions(driver); 
actions.moveToElement(e).click().perform();