# Getting Element is not clickable exception while click on a menu link

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on a menu link but not have any luck. It always showing exception -

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (64, 64). Other
>   element would receive the click: <
>    div style="position: absolute; left:
>   0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 30;
>   background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); opacity: 0.4;">

I have following  `html` snippet

```
<div id="RWR" class="clsDesktopHome" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: auto;">
    <div class="clsDesktop clsDesktopHomePage" style="width: 1553px; height: 430px; top: 0px; left: 15px;">
        <div id="foid:2" class="clsDesktopHeader clsTextOnDesktopColor">
            <div id="foid:1" class="clsDesktopTabs" style="margin-right: 230px; height: 28px; visibility: visible; width: auto;">
                <span class="clsDesktopTab clsDesktopTabActive clsDesktopTabTypeHome clsDesktopTabTypeHomeActive">
                    <span class="clsDesktopTabContent">
                        <span class="clsDesktopTabTypeIcon"></span>
                        <span class="clsDesktopTabMenuIcon"></span>
                        <span class="clsDesktopTabCollaborationIcon"></span>
                        <span class="clsDesktopTabCaption">Home</span>
                        <span class="clsDesktopTabCloseIcon"></span>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span class="clsDesktopTab clsDesktopTabInactive clsDesktopTabCanClose clsDesktopTabTypeSheet">
                <span class="clsDesktopTab clsDesktopTabInactive clsDesktopTabCanClose clsDesktopTabTypeSheet">
                <span class="clsDesktopTab clsDesktopTabInactive clsDesktopTabCanClose clsDesktopTabTypeSheet">
                <span class="clsDesktopTab clsDesktopTabInactive clsDesktopTabCanClose clsDesktopTabTypeSheet">
                <span class="clsDesktopTab clsDesktopTabInactive clsDesktopTabCanClose clsDesktopTabTypeSheet">
                <span class="clsDesktopTab clsDesktopTabInactive clsDesktopTabCanClose clsDesktopTabTypeSheet">
                <span class="clsDesktopTab clsDesktopTabInactive clsDesktopTabCanClose clsDesktopTabTypeSheet">
                <span class="clsDesktopTab clsDesktopTabHidden clsDesktopTabNoCaption clsDesktopTabTypeTabsMenu">
                <span class="clsDesktopTab clsDesktopTabInactive clsAddNewContainer clsDesktopTabTypeAddNew">
            </div>
        <div class="clsDesktopBelowTabs" style="height: 325px; visibility: visible;">
        <div id="foid:2" class="clsDesktopFooter clsTextOnDesktopColor" style="height: 18px; line-height: 18px;">
    </div>
    <div class="clsModalNode" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px; z-index: 10; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 30; background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); opacity: 0.4; display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

And this is the snapshot how it looking like -

[image]

I'm using following code to accomplish the same -

```
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='foid:1']/span[1]/span/span[4]"));
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));

   //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Home')]")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='foid:1']/span[1]/span/span[4]")).click();
```

I did inspect the `<div>` tag in DOM which accepting the click. But I'm seeing this

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 30; background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); opacity: 0.4;"></div>
```

with one additional attribute i.e. `display:none;`

Using following configurations:

1. `Selenium 3.0.1`
2. Driver -`ChromeDriver`

I don't know to to handle this situation.

Comment: Which driver are you using?

Comment: I'm using `ChromeDriver` .

Comment: Try using Javascript executor for clicking the element

Comment: Do you want to click on `Home` button??

Comment: @Saurabh, Yes I want to do so

Comment: Could you share more HTML with other tabs structure as well??

Comment: @amaurya123 I've tried `JavascriptExecuter`. not showing that exception but button didn't get clicked

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error

Comment: @Saurabh Gaur `html` updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to wait until element that gets click disappeared:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath('//div[@style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 30; background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); opacity: 0.4;"]')));
```

As this answer was downvoted, I add some more details to explain why it could be acceptable solution.

It's a known issue (I personally have faced it few times) of `chromedriver`: `chromedriver` sometimes ignores modal windows such as "Page loading in progress"

[image]

and "thinks" that target element (that is covered by modal window) actually visible and clickable and tries to make click which is received by modal window.

So it makes sense to wait until modal window disappeared.

Comment: @Andersson, You are absolutely right. This solution is working for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried many solution but it didn't work.Lastly i saw selenium docs and found [stalenessof](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#stalenessOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-)

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(findElement(By.xpath("element_path"))));
```

It should work now.