# Unable to locate element on web driver script

Tags: xpath, webdriver, firepath

I need to find an XPath for the below screenshot. Please help to write an XPath for the highlighted box.
I have tried

```
//span[contains(text(),'What's Up')]
```

and also

```
//span[@class='fontSize16' and contains(text(),'What's Up')]
```

P.S.: When I'm trying using to the XPath generated from firepath, i.e.

```
.//*[@id='appContent']/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1],
```

I'm getting below error(refer image2):

> Error :
>   FAILED: login
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point (627, 118). Other element would receive the click: 
>     (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)

[image: screeshot_1]

[image: Screenshot_2]

Comment: To create an XPath for you, we'll need some XML code by your XPath side. So far we cannot know on what data we should operate.

Comment: i m not sure what do you mean,how can i share xml plz help on same

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking: XPath does operate on XML (files), but you _did not provide_ any XML code. So what should/can we do?

Comment: `Element ... is not clickable at point` doesn't mean that you *"Unable to locate element"*! It means that you able to locate, but when you're trying to click it some other element receives the click. You might need to wait until element [becomes clickable](http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2014/01/how-to-wait-for-element-to-be-clickable.html) or until element that overlaps [becomes invisible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41632230/getting-element-is-not-clickable-exception-while-click-on-a-menu-link/41632565#41632565)