# Selenium to click a button

Tags: jquery, selenium

I am trying to use Selenium to click a button with the following HTML code:

```
<a id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_main_ucSearchResult_rptPager_ctl01_btnPageNumber" class="pager2"href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$cphMain$main$ucSearchResult$rptPager$ctl01$btnPageNumber','')">2</a>
```

I can find this button by using the following code:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_main_ucSearchResult_rptPager_ctl01_btnPageNumber")
```

but if I then do:

```
element.click()
```

I get an error message, namely:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <a id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_main_ucSearchResult_rptPager_ctl01_btnPageNumber" class="pager..." href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$cphMain$main$ucSearchResult$rptPager$ctl01$btnPageNumber','')">2</a> is not clickable at point (82, 516). Other element would receive the click: <p>...</p>
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64)
```

The URL I'm trying to navigate through is:

```
https://en.camping.info/campsites
```

Comment: Is it complete exception log? Can you share page `URL`?

Comment: URL: https://en.camping.info/campsites

Comment: added the exception log and URL to the question

Comment: Try adding `driver.find_element_by_id("btn-consent").click()` before clicking on the page buttons. I have a feeling the cookie info bar is covering up the the page buttons.

Comment: When I do:
driver.get("https://en.camping.info/campsites")
driver.find_element_by_id("btn-consent").click()
element = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_main_ucSearchResult_rptPager_ctl01_btnPageNumber")
element.click()

I get the exact same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 `div` elements that overlaps the pagination panel and receives the click. You might get rid of those `div` elements (hide them to be able to click on required button) with `JavaScriptExecutor` as below:

```
driver.get("en.camping.info/campsites")
page = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_main_ucSearchResult_rptPager_ctl01_btnPageNumber")
nav_div = driver.find_element_by_id('jq-app-buttons-wrapper')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].style.display="none";', nav_div)
cookies_div = driver.find_element_by_id('cookie-consent-wrapper')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].style.display="none";', cookies_div)
page.click()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_main_ucSearchResult_rptPager_ctl00_btnPageNumber"]''')
#I've used xpath here instead of id you can change that.

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elem).click().perform()
```

The issue here is that either One of 3 cases

1. Element is not visible or shown
2. Element has an overlay over it
3. Element is generated after the page is refreshed (Meaning it's not visible for a few seconds then it shows)

Great StackOverflow Explaining this

### [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19763087/6929467)

---

Comment: Will surely check this out, but you've been beaten by Mr. Andersson by a few minutes to be the accepted answer.

Comment: Yeah, awesome guy. He's diagnosed the problem and got a fix to it, his method is way better but requires a little bit more explanation (that'd be nice if he added some comments/documentation to what he's done since it might be confusing to someone that doesn't understand what's going on.
Great question too Monk, keep it up!