# Webdriver IO Loading overlay prevents click

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver-io

In [webdriver.io](http://webdriver.io)  I am trying to focus on element then click another element

the code looks like this:

```
browser.moveToObject(focusSelector)
                .click(clickSelector);
```

the issue is that the focus bring an loading overlay on the page and when I try to click some times the overlay is receiving the click, and the code fails with this exception:

```
unknown error: Element <div data-bo="UserMenu">...</div> is not clickable at point (1203, 28). 
Other element would receive the click: <div class="blockUI blockOverlay"></div>
```

so I need to wait when the overlay .blockUI will disappear and only then do the click....

I had tried to do:

```
browser.moveToObject(focusSelector);
browser.waitForExist('.blockUI', browser.options.waitforTimeout, true);
browser.click(clickSelector);
```

But this won't work cause after moveToObject ,the focus is lost and the click selector is not displayed.

while in:

```
browser.moveToObject(focusSelector)
                .click(clickSelector);
```

the focus is not lost... but then I have the overlay issue....

Any Ideas?

Comment: Don't use `block ui`.

Comment: for this scenario you can try with javascript executor.

Comment: We need to use block ui cause it's E2E testing.
Tried with  java script executor.. Didn't worked for me, can you give an example ?

Comment: @Murthi is suggesting `JavaScriptExecutor`, the Java version of WebdriverIO's of `execute`. I don't recommend it... it's so hackish and dirty, but it might get the job done in your second scenario (where you're chaining the commands). So instead of `click`, you would `execute` your JavaScript snippet in which you're clicking the element. But, as it stands it's pretty hard to debug unless you give us the **URL** so we can get a crack at it.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered **[in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error)**.

This worked for my Ajax Loader: `"Loading image ID"` (ID of the loading image) can be retrieved via Firebug.

```
By loadingImage = By.id("loading image ID");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(loadingImage));
```

Comment: This THE SAME THAT I DID AND IT'S NOT WORKING
browser.waitForExist('.blockUI', browser.options.waitforTimeout, true);

Comment: Talk about `a shot in the dark`... Dude, did you read his question beforehand? First off, get that dirty Java out of here: OP is running WebdriverIO (Selenium JavaScript bindings). Secondly that question you linked is older than life & most answers there are irrelevant to his scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid using the `moveToObject()` because it will soon be deprecated. In the event that you absolutely can't do that, try using:

```
browser.waitForVisible('.blockUI', null, true);
```

after the `moveToObject()` command. This waits until the element is no longer visible (the `null` means it'll wait for the default amount of milliseconds you set in your config file, and `true` means that the command is reversed - read more here: http://webdriver.io/api/utility/waitForVisible.html#Usage).

The `execute` option that was mentioned above would look like this:

```
browser.execute(() => {
   document.querySelector('[data-bo="UserMenu"]').click();
});
```

It is hacky but it gets the job done.