# Unable to click a button within selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I am struggling to click a continue button in my selenium. I try to use .click() but it states element is not clickable. I've tried waiting for the element to be visible before hand and even tried following the solutions in this article [Debugging "Element is not clickable at point" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error) but no luck.

Does any body know why this is being an issue? I am testing this in chrome.

```
<div class="basket-summary__continue"><button data-href="" data-component="Booking/Navigation/ContinueButton" class="bttn bttn--primary bttn--full-width">
    Continue
</button></div>
```

---

```
 public void ClickContinue()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
       _driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("basket-summary__continue")).FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/button")).Click();
    }
```

P.S I don't really want to use Thread.Sleep but just using it for now to create a wait.

Thank

Comment: can you give us the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: _driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(//button[@class='bttn bttn--primary bttn--full-width']")).click();

Comment: That xpath looks a prime candidate for the issue. Just for now I would place a unique ID on the <button> and do a Find element by Id. This should definitely work, you will need to wait for the render to finish.

Comment: @Murthi: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (1278, 4160)

Comment: when you are manually looking at it on the page, do you have to scroll down to click it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='basket-summary__continue']/button")
private WebElement button;
```

or

```
By buttonBy = By.xpath("//div[@class='basket-summary__continue']/button");
```

Then create an Explicit wait for Element clickable before clicking the button.

```
/***
 * An expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it.
 * @param locator - used to find the element
 * @param timeout
 * @return the WebElement once it is located and clickable (visible and enabled)
 */
public WebElement elementToBeClickable(By locator, int timeout) {
    try {
        return getWebDriverFluentWait(timeout)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

private Wait<WebDriver> getWebDriverFluentWait(int timeout) {
    return new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
}
```

Finally, we can perform the function like:

```
WebElement btnContinue = elementToBeClickable(buttonBy, 10); # wait for element clickable within 10 seconds timeout.
btnContinue.click();
```

// sorry that I am more on Java but I think we have the same solution for other language.

Comment: Hi Tony, sorry i am a little bit of a c# noob, do you first want me to create this first:       public void ClickContinue()
        {
            _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='basket-summary__continue']/button"));
            private WebElement button;

    }

Comment: I have updated with a few more code in the answer. Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for element to be clickable -- i.e. is visible and enabled -- using ExpectedConditions class.

Please, check the following doc:
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementToBeClickable.htm

Comment: I tried element to be clickable before and gave it 10 seconds but it would still have an issue