# Having trouble clicking on a button using id, xpath, class, etc

Tags: python, selenium, button, xpath, webdriver

I have a button that I'm trying to click and need some help from the group. This button is found in the backend / admin area of my wordpress site (I'm trying to mass upload data into a directory listing system). I'm thinking that I need to use the button class because there are two data-id elements with the same number on the same page. I have provided my selenium code (python) attempts as well as the html I'm trying to access. Any help appreciated!!

HTML:

```
<div class="pkg-button">
    <a data-id="38579" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary button select-plan">Select</a>
</div>
```

Here's the html code snippet that has the conflicting id.

```
<ul data-price="0"  data-subscribed='0' data-id="38579" data-type="1"  class="packagelistitems " >
```

=============

Code Method 1:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("38579").click()
```

Code Method 2:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn btn-lg btn-primary button select-plan').click()
```

Code Method 3:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("btn btn-lg btn-primary button select-plan")
for e in elements:
    e.click()
```

Code Method 4:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="plan"]/div[1]/ul/li/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/a').click()
```

For this last code snippet (#4), I'm getting the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <a data-id="38579" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary button select-plan">...</a> is not clickable at point (659, 14). Other element would receive the click: <div id="wpadminbar" class="">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear why element is not clickable (probably you should click on `div` wrapper and not an `a` element), so try these, something should work)

to click on `div`:

```
//div[@class='pkg-button'][a[text()='Select']]
```

to click on `a` tag

```
//div[@class='pkg-button']/a[text()='Select']

//a[text()='Select']
```

**Important:** Please note that in method4 you received error where element with id `wpadminbar` overlapped your item, so check this in browser dev tools to be sure that some div is not overlapping element you want to click =)

Comment: I used all 3 of your strings using "find_element_by_xpath", ".click()". Errors are:

div string:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/div[@class='pkg-button'][a[text()='Select']]"}

a tag #1:
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <a data-id="38579" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary button select-plan">...</a> is not clickable at point (627, 14). Other element would receive the click: <div id="wpadminbar" class="">...</div>

Comment: a tag #2:
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <a data-id="38579" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary button select-plan">...</a> is not clickable at point (627, 14). Other element would receive the click: <div id="wpadminbar" class="">...</div>

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pkg-button'] [a[text()='Select']]").click()
```

in this way you select the element with `class="pkg-button"`

Comment: On the click event line of your code, I'm getting the following error:
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <a data-id="38579" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary button select-plan">...</a> is not clickable at point (627, 14). Other element would receive the click: <div id="wpadminbar" class="">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)

Comment: bad idea to click pkg-button without additional specification, as it could be not unique

Comment: @VitaliyMoskalyuk you are right. I re-edited the answer

Comment: There is more than one Select button on the page (ie., they pertain to product packages for the listing). I use the MRI xpath highlight tool (bookmarklet for IE) and it using the following string highlights all the Select buttons: //div[@class='pkg-button']

Comment: Retried your edit. Getting: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <div class="pkg-button">...</div> is not clickable at point (627, 14). Other element would receive the click: <div id="wpadminbar" class="">...</div>

Comment: @user3280396 could you share your entire html?

Comment: I can share the html file. However, it has more characters than what the edit field will allow & I cannot attach files in the stackoverflow.com thread. I can ftp something up and share the link. Is there another way to share files on this forum?

Answer (score 0):

`find_element_by_id` is searching for unique `id` attribute, not custom named attributes like `data-id`

try this:

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-id='38579']").click()

Comment: Getting the following: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <a data-id="38579" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary button select-plan">...</a> is not clickable at point (627, 14). Other element would receive the click: <div id="wpadminbar" class="">...</div>

Comment: refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error

Answer (score 0):

You could try

linkText directly since its a link with Text

`find_element_by_link_text("Select")`

Css

`div.pkg-button>a[data-id='38579']`

or

`div[class='pkg-button']>a[data-id='38579']`

or lastly XPATH

`.//div[@class='pkg-button']/a[text()='Select']`

While your attempts do not work because,

1. `elem = driver.find_element_by_id("38579").click()` This doesn't work since there is no element which has "id" attribute matching below, "data-id" is different than "id"
2. `driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn btn-lg btn-primary button select-plan').click()` This selector is broad. There could be many elements available, and it could click on something that you may don't desire
3. `elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("btn btn-lg btn-primary button select-plan")
   for e in elements:
       e.click()` Similar to #2 above, something could randomly fail before it could click on the element you wish for
4. `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="plan"]/div[1]/ul/li/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/a').click()`
    This is just way to brittle selector, I don't expect it to work. Neither you could write selenium scripts with such selectors, your automation will fail left, right and center.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at using the find_element_by_css_selector. 
For the above, using your browser, right on the part of the html code of interest, click on "copy" and then "copy selector".

[How to css selector.](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/27156/how-to-find-a-button-by-cssselector)

Comment: I was able to solve the problem with the code noted below. My issue was that I was interacting with an object at the bottom of the page, but the button I'm trying to click was midway on the page. Seems that the object I want to interact with has to be physically viewable at the time of script interaction. Is this true? I would think that all objects are loaded into memory and could be accessed randomly. Someone please comment on this.

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="plan"]/div[1]/ul/li/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/a').click()

Comment: Yes. In selenium the element has to be visible and intractable else you will be unable to complete the action. This is more like simulating a user action.