# Protractor: Cannot identify elements after Chrome browser is set to zoom 50%

Tags: protractor

I am working on a project where the application is deployed on a kiosk machine after development and QA. Since i have to test it on my local machine, the default size (i.e.100%) of the application in the browser moves out of the window without any scroll bars, hence it becomes difficult to trace the element.
Therefore, i am reducing the size from 100% to 50% through script.

```
browser.get("url");
browser.driver.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='50%'");
browser.findElement(by.xpath("WebElement")).click();
```

Error:
Failed: unknown error: Element

Comment: This doesn't seems like full error message. Can you add the whole error message.

Comment: Also, you don't use this syntax in Protractor - `findElement`

Comment: Full Error Message:

Failures:
1) 
  Message:
[31m    Failed: unknown error: Element <div class="NavigateBox square yellow" style="background-image:url(/content/dam/partners/walgreens/images/send_money_select_service.jpg)">...</div> is not clickable at point (536, 490). Other element would receive the click: <div class="footer">...</div>
      (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)[0m

Answer (score 1):

In Protractor, the syntax comes in this format

`element(by.xpath("valid_xpath"))`

```
browser.get("url");
browser.driver.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='50%'");
element(by.xpath("xpath_here")).click()
```

Edit 1: Since OP provided the correct error message, the error seems that due to the change in resolution the element might not be visible or be overlapped with a `span` or `div` element, which is the reason why the `click` event is going to another co-ordinates.

Please refer to this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error), where this error has been discussed in detail along with the remedy steps.

Comment: It does not work. Error: Failed: unknown error. 
if i comment this "browser.driver.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='50%'");"
and execute then it identifies the element but it is of no use since requirement is to keep zoom at 50%

Comment: Since you're zooming it to a different resolution, most probably the element is not in the view or the xpath changed. See how the DOM changes due to the resolution change and you'll figure it out.

Comment: i verified, xpath does not change, it remains the same. i have highlighted the web button at runtime through script using xpath for both 100% and 50% zoom, both the time buttton gets highlighted, but is not clickable at 50%