# Element not clickable since another element obscures it in python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, ui-automation

I am trying to automate an access point web configuration. During this, I get a pop up (kind of an overlay with "Yes" and "No") which i want to click on

The HTML code for the overlay that I am trying to click on:

```
<div id="generic-warning-dialog" class="dialog exclamation text-orphan" style="">
<div class="warning-content dialog-content text-orphan">Security Mode is disabled on one or more of your wireless networks. Your network could be open to unauthorized users. Are you sure you wish&nbsp;to&nbsp;proceed?</div>
    <div class="dialog-buttons text-orphan">
        <button class="cancel">No</button>
        <button class="submit" style="display: block;">Yes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
```

but I get the following error:

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message:
>   Element  is not
>   clickable at point (788,636.5) because another element 
>   obscures it

Can you please advise on how should i proceed?
I am using firefox and python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging "Element is not clickable at point" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error)

Comment: try to give explicit wait before clicking on the element.

Comment: How Does the explicit wait help? I tried it through the python console by giving each individual command so I don’t think it’s got to do with the page not getting loaded.

Comment: This is not an issue with Python. This is an issue with Selenium and Firefox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your question and the *HTML* you have shared, you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

```
#to click on Yes button
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='warning-content dialog-content text-orphan' and contains(.,'Security Mode is disabled')]//following::div[1]//button[@class='submit']"))).click()
# to click on No button
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='warning-content dialog-content text-orphan' and contains(.,'Security Mode is disabled')]//following::div[1]//button[@class='cancel']"))).click()
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I get this error                                                                                                            
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='warning-content dialog-content text-orphan' and contains(.,'Security Mode is disabled')]//button[@class='submit']"))).click()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

Comment: @Klot Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: @ DebanjanB upvoted the answer. can you explain how the command works

Comment: @Klot In my solution I have induced a waiter to wait for the _element to turn clickable_ and once the state of the element becomes intractable we invoked `click()` method directly. let me know if you have any further queries.

Comment: This did not work for me. It seems like button is already "clickable" but clicking it still leads to "obscure error" - in my case it is a button within a foundation reveal/modal (see https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/reveal.html) Any ideas?

Comment: I've got the same problem as @Henhuy. Even though I wait for the element to be clickable, it still throws `ElementClickInterceptedException`. I will just go with `invisibility_of_element` to wait for the blocking object to become invisible.

Answer (score 6):

You can Replace click event with action class

**Using Action Class :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element("Your Web Element").click().perform()
```

Comment: for the "Your web element" i used                                                                                                   >>> element=browser.find_element_by_class_name("submit")                                  
>>> actions = ActionChains(browser)
>>> actions.move_to_element(element).click().perform()                                                 Is that correct? This does not work

Comment: @Klot Yes correct. If not working, What is an exception ?

Comment: Did not get any error but it was unable to click the button. The overlay window was still being displayed after executing this.