# ElementClickInterceptedException in Selenium when the element is only partially obscured

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-webdriver-python

I'm using Selenium for testing. I want to click on an element. The element is very much clickable and visible, but it happens that the *middle point* of the element is obscured, causing the error.

Here is a MCVE:

HTML code [(link to demo)](https://repl.it/@alexmojaki/BlissfulPreciousLanservers):

```html
<style>
    button {
        width: 90vw;
        height: 90vh;
        position: fixed;
        top: 5vh;
        left: 5vw;
    }

    .cover {
        background: grey;
        opacity: 0.3;
        width: 80vw;
        height: 80vh;
        position: fixed;
        top: 10vh;
        left: 10vw;
    }
</style>

<button onclick="alert('hi');">
  Click me!
</button>

<div class="cover">
  I'm in the way!
</div>
```

Python selenium code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://blissfulpreciouslanservers--five-nine.repl.co/")
button = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("button")
button.click()
```

Result:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button onclick="alert('hi');">...</button> is not clickable at point (451, 450). Other element would receive the click: <div class="cover">...</div>
```

This seems like a rather sad limitation of Selenium. The button is clickable, just not at all points. I don't want to have to fiddle with scrolling and coordinates.

There are many similar questions about the exception in general, e.g:

- [Can not click on a Element: ElementClickInterceptedException in Splinter / Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48665001/can-not-click-on-a-element-elementclickinterceptedexception-in-splinter-selen)
- [Selenium can't click element because other element obscures it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49921128/selenium-cant-click-element-because-other-element-obscures-it?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Element not clickable since another element obscures it in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51511142/element-not-clickable-since-another-element-obscures-it-in-python)

However the questions are never specifically about an element that is only *partially* obscured, so I haven't managed to find a proper answer to my own question. The answers to other questions generally fall into these categories:

1. Wait until the element is clickable. Doesn't apply here.
2. Use action chains, e.g. `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()`. This doesn't help because `.move_to_element()` [moves to the middle of the element](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.move_to_element).
3. Use JavaScript to perform the click. It seems like I might have to resort to this, but it's very unsatisfactory. I still want to validate that the element is clickable at least somewhere and not bypass all checks.

Comment: Action chains can move by offset after as well so you can move to a certain x,y position.

Comment: @arundeepchohan doing that manually make the test significantly harder to write and maintain. I'd like to avoid it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to add a `class` to your button and then search for the class? For example:

```
<button class="btn" onclick="alert('hi');">
  Click me!
</button>
```

Then use the following to find and click on that button:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("btn")).click();
```

similar to this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27529967/how-to-find-button-element-with-webdriver) response by [alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe)

Comment: I have no problem finding the element, the problem is with clicking on it.