# How to click on a label in webpage to expand it

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

HTML :

```
<label for="header-nav-toggle" class="header-nav__toggle">Menu</label>
```

On clicking the Menu in the webpage the user is displayed with the `SignOut` option.

How to write an XPath for this action ??

For the XPath

```
$x("//*[@id='root']/div/main/div/header/div/label")
```

in the chrome - Devtools-Console I got

```
[label.header-nav__toggle]
0: label.header-nav__toggle
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Need to select the 0: value. Facing error like

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error:
    Element <label for="header-nav-toggle" class="header-nav__toggle">...</label>
    is not clickable at point (1236, 52). Other element would receive the click:
    <div class="sc-ifAKCX cHaoWT" data-delay="250"></div>
```

Comment: Functionally, a `<label>` doesn't associates with any `onClick()` event (barring special scenarios). Possibly you should look out for a following `<input>` tag and update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this solution, based on given HTML and Exception type:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@class='header-nav__toggle' and contains(text(),'Menu')]"))).click().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding waits before clicking the element.

Or use javascript to click the element.

More here:
[Debugging "Element is not clickable at point" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error).