# Selenium Webdriver, clicking a button not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having two issues in clicking two buttons during my automation

**First :** A View button which have the following Details

```
<button class="veiw-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".toggle-content1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="toggle-content1" ng-click="gotoAnchor(flightResult.FlightId)">VIEW</button>
```

There are several VIEW buttons on the page but they are differentiated with the toggle-content (they have numbers 1,2,3,4) I just need to select the first one and click on it

Second :

After clicking the View i want to also click the Continue Button  with the following code

```
<div class="text-center">
    <button class="flight-book-btn" type="button" ng-click="select(false, flightResult);">
     <span>Continue</span>
     </button>
</div>
```

My Major issue is the First Code but if i can get help with both i will be glad . I have not been able to click on the First VIEW Button

i have tried some samples online but they have not worked for me

I expect to be able to click the VIEW and Continue Buttons

CODE:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);     
log.debug("Fastest Sort Available "); 
log.debug("Now about to click VIEW Airline Details "); 
// driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='VIEW' and @data-target='.toggle-content1' and @aria-controls='toggle-content1']")).click();; 
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class=\"veiw-btn\"][data-target='.toggle-content1'']")).click();
```

Comment: Please provide the code and/or errors, if you can.

Comment: driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    
    log.debug("Fastest Sort Available ");
   log.debug("Now about to click VIEW Airline Details  ");
    
   
// driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='VIEW' and @data-target='.toggle-content1' and @aria-controls='toggle-content1']")).click();;
    
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class=\"veiw-btn\"][data-target='.toggle-content1'']")).click();

Comment: use Action: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52811266/webdriverexception-element-is-not-clickable-in-selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52811266/webdriverexception-element-is-not-clickable-in-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the css selector or Xpath

**CSS:**

`driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button[class="veiw-btn"][data-target='.toggle-content1']").Click();`

**xpath:**

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='veiw-btn'][@data-target='.toggle-content1']").Click();
```

Comment: I'm getting this error for the codes. Same error that its not clickable                                            org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <button class="veiw-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".toggle-content1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="toggle-content1" ng-click="gotoAnchor(flightResult.FlightId)">...</button> is not clickable

Comment: @Adeyinka Alayo give us the whole HTML page so we can figure out what is intercepting the click, or at least the whole section where the button is located

Answer (score 0):

You can use this xpath to click on **VIEW** button :

```
//button[text()='VIEW' and @data-target='.toggle-content1' and @aria-controls='toggle-content1']
```

For clicking on Continue button you can try with this xpath :

```
//span[text()='Continue']/parent::button[@class='flight-book-btn']
```

Comment: 'm getting this error for the codes. Same error that its not clickable org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <button class="veiw-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".toggle-content1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="toggle-content1" ng-click="gotoAnchor(flightResult.FlightId)">...</button> is not clickable –

Comment: @AdeyinkaAlayo : Can you share your code, what did you try ?

Comment: I have tried all the options stated for now and the error is that the View Button is not clickable whereas it is a  try {
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
log.debug("Fastest Sort Available ");
log.debug("Now about to click VIEW Airline Details  ");
 
// driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='VIEW' and @data-target='.toggle-content1' and @aria-controls='toggle-content1']")).click();;
    
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class=\"veiw-btn\"][data-target='.toggle-content1'']")).click();

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed this by  using this

WebElement element=  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='VIEW' and @data-target='.toggle-content1' and @aria-controls='toggle-content1']"));
            JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);