# Can we click a button which is overlapped by some image/button using java and selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to click a button which is overlapped by some image, but it is not getting clicked, Can some please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of your code. Add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including proper example input/output data.

Comment: Do you know how users of the app are supposed to click a button that is hidden by some image? Answering this question in your initial question may help to find a better solution. So far the answer provided by @Rostyslav Barmakov looks acceptable

Comment: Read through this discussion, this might give you some [ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error).

Comment: I consider this an issue, you may want to report it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JavascriptExecutor` to hide image and then do what you need:

```
// hide image
WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.id("image"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('display', 'none')", image);

// click button
driver.findElement(By.id("button")).click();

// display image
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('display', 'block')", image);
```