# Clicking specific nested "a" tags when scraping with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

i am trying to scrape information from this link https://www.hopkinsguides.com/hopkins/index/Johns_Hopkins_ABX_Guide/Antibiotics

This site uses jquery. My goal is to scrape all the antibiotic names, then for each antibiotic scrape "NON-FDA APPROVED USES" which is contained in a separate link. I hope i'm making sense.

The antibiotics are in categories that contain MANY other subcategories that contain the rest of antibiotics with their respective link.

My program first logs in, and the clicks on the first 7 buttons to expand and show more categories. I used `driver.find_element_by_x_path` to expand the first layer but i cant expand the second layer the same way (by looping through x_path) because if i do it will end up taking me to the other page where the "NON-FDA APPROVED USES" info is contained instead of expanding the page.

It does so because once u expand the first layer, then the second layer now contains more buttons/subcategories AND links that take you to the page where "NON-FDA APPROVED USES".

So if these are my x_paths

```
#//*[@id="firstul"]/li[1]/a 
#//*[@id="firstul"]/li[2]/a
```

li[1] could be a redirecting link, 
li[2] could be a button that shows more links(which is what i want first)

I made a soup to separate the buttons from links but now i cant click on the "a" tags i printed out in the bottom for loop.

Any ideas on how i should go about this?? Thanks in advance.

Here's my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from random import randint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup




#SIGN-IN
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.hopkinsguide.com/home")
url = "https://www.hopkinsguides.com/hopkins/index/"

assert "Hopkins" in driver.title
sign_in_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="logout"]')
sign_in_button.click()

user_elem = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
pass_elem = driver.find_element_by_id('dd-password')
user_elem.send_keys("user")
time.sleep(2)
pass_elem.send_keys("pass")
time.sleep(2)
sign_in_after_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dd-login-button"]')
sign_in_after_input.click()

def expand_page():    
    req = driver.get("https://www.hopkinsguides.com/hopkins/index/Johns_Hopkins_ABX_Guide/Antibiotics")
    time.sleep(randint(2, 4))
    #expand first layer
    for i in range(1, 8):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='firstul']/li[" + str(i) + "]/a").click()
        time.sleep(2)

    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='lxml')
    for i in soup.find_all('a'):
        if i.get('data-path') != None:
            print(i)
            time.sleep(2)

expand_page()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to expand all the expandable nodes first before accessing the underlying links one by one. From what I can see of the site, the discriminating attribute would be `<li class="expandable index-expand">` and `<li class="index-leaf">`.

You can use Selenium to locate the "expandable index-expand" classes and click the nested `<a>` tag first. Then, repeat the same operation for the expanded child layer each time you click. Once you no longer detect "expandable index-expand" classes in the child layer, you can proceed to grab the links from "index-leaf".

`find_elements_by_class_name` should do the trick

Comment: Hey thank you very much. It seems like you can't click <li> attribute... the clickable tag is attribute is `<a role='button'>`.

Comment: @Joelalexis Yes, but you're able to use it to locate the nested ```<a>``` tags and click them. Let me update my answer for accuracy's sake :)

Answer (score 0):

To expand all the values this should work for you, this will expand all the first level values and keep checking if any child values are expandable by checking the `role` attribute of element recursively:

```
def click_further(driver, elem):
    subs = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda driver: elem.find_elements_by_xpath("./following-sibling::ul//li/a"))
    for sub in subs:
        if sub.get_attribute('role') == "button":
            sub.click()
            click_further(driver, sub)

for idx in range(1,8):
    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='firstul']/li[{}]/a".format(idx))))
    elem.click()
    click_further(driver, elem)
```

I guess then you can figure out how to get the text which you want to extract from it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I ran it and got this error. Also i found this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error `>Aminoglycosides</a> is not clickable at point (311, 10). Other element would receive the click: <a href="https://www.hopkinsguides.com/hopkins/prime">...</a>`

Comment: @Joelalexis, sorry I could not reproduce the same error on my Windows/Ubuntu, but were you able to solve that issue with the changes suggested in the link you shared?