# Xpath working in Chrome browser but same Xpath is not working in Firefox browser

Tags: java, selenium

I am working on Page Object Module this is my xpath

```
By Organization = By.xpath("//input[@value='Organization']");
```

Same Xpath working on Chrome browser and not working on Firefox browser. On Firefox browser following error appearing is:

```
Selected checkbox type is = Organization
Element <input id="TypeOfClient" name="TypeOfClient" type="radio"> is not clickable at point (618,160) because another element <div id="divLoadimg" class="modalTabelGray"> obscures it
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'NAV-L186', ip: '192.168.0.186', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_212'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 68.0.1, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:buildID: 20190717172542, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.24.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 47144, moz:profile: C:\Users\zafar.ahmad\AppDat..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 1fa44ff4-7c0d-4f61-b7bd-0dea567b2b77
```

Comment: The `xpath` worked fine, the element was located. The problem is you can't click on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging "Element is not clickable at point" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error)

Answer (score 0):

As error says there is a loading image wait till  loading image is being disappeared