# "Element is not clickable at point" has the wrong co-ordinates

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I'm receiving this error while trying to use `browser.click()` with [webdriver.io](https://webdriver.io):

```
Error: element click intercepted: Element <input type="text" class="form-control" 
id="nameInput" data-validate="true" data-required-error="Name is required." 
data-pattern-error="Invalid data entered for Name" pattern="^.*$" required="" 
maxlength="255" value="Some Other Name"> is not clickable at point (709, 483). 
Other element would receive the click: <div class="attribute-container col-sm-6">...</div>
```

This is super weird because the div that it's complaining about is below where I'm trying to click.  I also took a screen capture and measured the screen with SnagIt.  The x,y value is too far off where it should be!

Why is Chrome missing my element?  I have lots of other things that webdriver.io clicks on correctly.  It seems everything in this one fixed panel cannot be clicked on.  Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!  It's because I used the `zoom` CSS attribute on that div.  There's a [bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=967097&q=getBoundingClientRect&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) where when you set the zoom attribute, it messes with the x, y offset and then Chrome is clicking in the wrong place.

To test if this is your issue, once your test fails to click in the right place, assuming it was trying to click on `#nameInput` run this in the console (press F12 to get to it) to figure out what Chrome "thinks" is the co-ordinates of your element:

```
document.getElementById("nameInput").getBoundingClientRect();
```

Note the x and y coordinates.  In my case, the co-ordinates were (which match my error):

```
x: 633.9236450195312
y: 467.98614501953125
```

Next, I ran this script to place a 5px red block at that point in the screen to see where it was clicking.  I just cut & pasted it into the console:

```
myMarker = document.createElement("div");

myMarker.style.cssText = `
  height: 5px; 
  width: 5px; 
  background: #ff0000; 
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 483px;
  left: 709px;
  z-index: 10000;
  `;

myMarker.id = "myMarker";
document.body.appendChild(myMarker);
```

It's off!  The red arrow in the picture below shows element I'm trying to click on, and the green arrow shows the red dot that I added at the co-ordinate that it's trying to click.

[image]

What can you do to fix it?  The best I can tell is to NOT use the zoom CSS property (which also apparently isn't supported in Firefox).  Or you could possibly click on the element using JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

Try to click on the button by using java script. It will work. I was also getting the same problem earlier that button was not clickable when we changed the Zoom level of chrome browser. But when we tried to click on the button by using javascript it worked.

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment.

Comment: Yeah. This is not a good idea. What if the button isn't visible by accident? JS will still click on it even though a user cannot. Your test will provide false positives that the code is okay.