# How do I use python requests to web scrape the filtered results?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the filtered results from this website https://www.gurufocus.com/insider/summary. Now I can only get the info from the first page. But what I really want to do is to filter several industries and get relevant data (you can see 'industry' on the filter area). But when I choose the industry, the web URL won't change and I can't scrape directly from URL. I saw some people said you can use `requests.post` to get the data but I don't really know how that works.

Here are some of my codes right now.

```
TradeUrl = "https://www.gurufocus.com/insider/summary"
r = requests.get(TradeUrl)
data=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

ticker = []
for tk in soup.find_all('td',{'class': 'table-stock-info', 'data-column': 'Ticker'}):
    ticker.append(tk.text)
```

What should I do if I only need tickers from the financial services industry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem using the post requests as suggested is that the request needs a authorization token which has an expiry time on. You can see the post request in Chrome or Firefox if you right click on the page -> select `Inspect` -> select `Network` then select an `Industry` click on the POST request and click on `Cookies` there is a cookie `password_grant_custom.client.expires` which has a timestamp of when the Authorization will no longer work.

However you can use selenium to scrape data off all pages.

First install Selenium:

```
`sudo pip3 install selenium` on Linux or `pip install selenium` on Windows
```

Then get a driver https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads, 
get the right one for your version of Chrome and extract it from the zip file.

*Note* on Windows you will need to add the path to you chromedriver to

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

On Linux copy chromedriver to `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

# Start with the driver maximised to see the drop down menus properly
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.gurufocus.com/insider/summary')

# Set the page size to 100 to reduce page loads
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'40 / Page')]").click()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((
        By.XPATH,
        "//div[contains(text(),'100')]"))
)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'100')]").click()

# Wait for the page to load and don't overload the server
time.sleep(2)

# select Industry
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Industry')]").click()

# Select Financial Services
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((
        By.XPATH,
        "//span[contains(text(),'Financial Services')]"))
)
element.click()

ticker = []

while True:
    # Wait for the page to load and don't overload the server
    time.sleep(6)
    # Parse the HTML
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    for tk in soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'table-stock-info', 'data-column': 'Ticker'}):
        ticker.append(tk.text)
    try:
        # Move to the next page
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn-next')))
        element.click()
    except TimeoutException as ex:
        # No more pages so break
        break
driver.quit()

print(len(ticker))
print(ticker)
```

Output

```
4604
['PUB   ', 'ARES   ', 'EIM   ', 'CZNC   ', 'SSB   ', 'CNA   ', 'TURN   ', 'FNF   ', 'EGIF   ', 'NWPP  etc...
```

**UPDATED**

If you want to scrape all the data off all the pages and/or write to a csv use pandas:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import pandas as pd
import time

# Start with the driver maximised to see the drop down menus properly
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.gurufocus.com/insider/summary')

# Set the page size to 100 to reduce page loads
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'40 / Page')]").click()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((
        By.XPATH,
        "//div[contains(text(),'100')]"))
)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'100')]").click()

# Wait for the page to load and don't overload the server
time.sleep(2)

# select Industry
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Industry')]").click()

# Select Financial Services
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((
        By.XPATH,
        "//span[contains(text(),'Financial Services')]"))
)
element.click()


columns = [
    'Ticker', 'Links', 'Company', 'Price1', 'Insider Name', 'Insider Position',
    'Date', 'Buy/Sell', 'Insider Trading Shares', 'Shares Change', 'Price2',
    'Cost(000)', 'Final Share', 'Price Change Since Insider Trade (%)',
    'Dividend Yield %', 'PE Ratio', 'Market Cap ($M)', 'None'
]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)


while True:
    # Wait for the page to load and don't overload the server
    time.sleep(6)
    # Parse the HTML
    df = df.append(pd.read_html(driver.page_source, attrs={'class': 'data-table'})[0], ignore_index=True)

    try:
        # Move to the next page
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn-next')))
        element.click()
    except TimeoutException as ex:
        # No more pages so break
        break
driver.quit()

# Write to csv
df.to_csv("Financial_Services.csv", encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

**Updated in response to comments:**
First download  the Firefox driver geckodriver from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases extract the driver. Again on Windows you will need to add the path to your geckodriver to `driver = webdriver.Firefox()` or on linux copy geckodriver to /usr/local/bin/geckodriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import pandas as pd
import time

# Start with the driver maximised to see the drop down menus properly
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.gurufocus.com/insider/summary')

# Set the page size to 100 to reduce page loads
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'40 / Page')]").click()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((
        By.XPATH,
        "//div[contains(text(),'100')]"))
)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'100')]").click()

# Wait for the page to load and don't overload the server
time.sleep(2)

# select Industry
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Industry')]").click()

# Select Financial Services
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((
        By.XPATH,
        "//span[contains(text(),'Financial Services')]"))
)
element.click()

columns = [
    'Ticker', 'Links', 'Company', 'Price1', 'Insider Name', 'Insider Position',
    'Date', 'Buy/Sell', 'Insider Trading Shares', 'Shares Change', 'Price2',
    'Cost(000)', 'Final Share', 'Price Change Since Insider Trade (%)',
    'Dividend Yield %', 'PE Ratio', 'Market Cap ($M)', 'None'
]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
page_limit = 5
page = 0

while True:
    # Wait for the page to load and don't overload the server
    time.sleep(6)
    # Parse the HTML
    df = df.append(pd.read_html(driver.page_source, attrs={'class': 'data-table'})[0], ignore_index=True)

    # Stop after page limit is reached.
    page = page + 1
    if page >= page_limit:
        break

    try:
        # Move to the next page
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn-next')))
        element.click()
    except TimeoutException as ex:
        # No more pages so break
        break

driver.quit()

# Write to csv
df.to_csv("Financial_Services.csv", encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much but I tried to run the code and get the error of ```element click intercepted: Element <span>...</span> is not clickable at point (502, 81)```. Do you know how to deal with this problem?

Comment: I think I tried several times and it worked this time somehow. How do I limit the page though? What should I do if I only want to go through the first five pages?

Comment: I have seen the error `Element <span>...</span> is not clickable at point` before it is due to a bug in the chromedriver see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error the easiest way to fix it is to use the Firefox driver geckodriver https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases I'll post an update to address both your comments shortly.

Comment: Sorry for the late response and thank you sooooo much for the detailed answer!! Those are really really helpful and my problems are solved right now. I really appreciate it! Try to learn some selenium from now on lol

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer using the buttons to the left of it if it answered your question