# How do I prevent errors when clicking an element on the page but element is not clickable?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch

I am writing a test for an element on the page, but when I use pageObject.click("@MyElement) on the element, sometimes it throws this error:

```
Element <i class="...">...</i> is not clickable at point (25, 299). Other element would receive the click: <div class =...></div>
```

I have tried using pageObject.waitForElementVisible("@selector"), but it does not work.I don't know why this only happends sometimes, while other times the tests don't fail.
Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debugging "Element is not clickable at point" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error)

Comment: No, because i use javascript, JavascriptExecutor and Actions didn't work because they are not defined

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there's an overlay element which is invisible and blocking the 'path' to the element you want to click.

In my case the following works great:

```
browser.moveToElement(using, element, 1, 1);
browser.mouseButtonClick(0);
```