# Element <span> is not clickable at point (1039,84) because another element <div class="_2dDPU CkGkG"> obscures it

Tags: python, selenium, bots

Im trying to click the like button with selenium this is the exception error I'm getting:

```
[-] Passed One Message: Element <span class="glyphsSpriteHeart__filled__16__white u-__7"> is not clickable at point (1039,84) because another element <div class="_2dDPU   CkGkG"> obscures it
```

I have tried solving it with a loop that clicks all of the aria label like elements with Xpath, see my code:

```
        while count <= likes:
            try:
                likeopt = bot.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@aria-label='Like'] ")
                for likeopti in likeopt:
                    likeopti.click()
                    #bot.find_element_by_class_name("fr66n").click()
                    print("[+] Liked !", count)
                    count += 1
                time.sleep(random.randint(8, 15))
                bot.find_element_by_class_name("_65Bje").click()
                time.sleep(random.randint(8, 15))
            except Exception as e:
                try:
                    bot.find_element_by_class_name("_65Bje").click()
                    time.sleep(random.randint(3, 7))
                    print("[-] Passed One", e)
                except Exception as x:
                    bot.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@aria-label='Close'] ")
                    continue
                    print(x,"[+]click on X, finished all posts")
```

How do you think can it can be solved?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debugging "Element is not clickable at point" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error)

Comment: you can also remove the offending piece of the DOM from the DOM once you've located it.

Comment: Can you share a link to the site?

Answer (score -1):

Watch your script running, and pay attention to the point where it fails.  You will likely see that there's some sort of drop down menu, pop-up 'dialog', or even an advertisement, that has displayed over your target link.  You'll need to close/dismiss this to be able to get at the target link.

Alternatively, you can hack it by instructing the driver to send a click command via Javascript.  `bot.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", likeopt)`  I typically save this approach as a last resort since it does not represent how a user would interact with the page.